# Equivalent of Numpy.argsort() in basic python?

Tags: python, numpy

is there a builtin function of Python that does on `python.array` what [`argsort()`](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List_With_Doc#head-82d26af744a08992cf3422d6df9dc9e276e78263) does on a `numpy.array`?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I timed the suggestions above and here are my results.

```
import timeit
import random
import numpy as np

def f(seq):
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382352/equivalent-of-numpy-argsort-in-basic-python/3383106#3383106
    #non-lambda version by Tony Veijalainen
    return [i for (v, i) in sorted((v, i) for (i, v) in enumerate(seq))]

def g(seq):
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382352/equivalent-of-numpy-argsort-in-basic-python/3383106#3383106
    #lambda version by Tony Veijalainen
    return [x for x,y in sorted(enumerate(seq), key = lambda x: x[1])]


def h(seq):
    #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382352/equivalent-of-numpy-argsort-in-basic-python/3382369#3382369
    #by unutbu
    return sorted(range(len(seq)), key=seq.__getitem__)


seq = list(range(10000))
random.shuffle(seq)

n_trials = 100
for cmd in [
        'f(seq)', 'g(seq)', 'h(seq)', 'np.argsort(seq)',
        'np.argsort(seq).tolist()'
        ]:
    t = timeit.Timer(cmd, globals={**globals(), **locals()})
    print('time for {:d}x {:}: {:.6f}'.format(n_trials, cmd, t.timeit(n_trials)))
```

output

```
time for 100x f(seq): 0.323915
time for 100x g(seq): 0.235183
time for 100x h(seq): 0.132787
time for 100x np.argsort(seq): 0.091086
time for 100x np.argsort(seq).tolist(): 0.104226
```

A problem size dependent analysis is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57028877/7128154).

Comment: Interesting - probably the average is more important than the 'best' of 3(?)

Comment: The average is affected by outliers. You do not want the results be polluted by other programs running or hardware cache misses happenstances.

Comment: For future readers, `%timeit` is reporting the best average from 3 averages of 100 loops each.

Answer (score 108):

There is no built-in function, but it's easy to assemble one out of the terrific tools Python makes available:

```
def argsort(seq):
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071415/efficient-method-to-calculate-the-rank-vector-of-a-list-in-python
    return sorted(range(len(seq)), key=seq.__getitem__)

x = [5,2,1,10]

print(argsort(x))
# [2, 1, 0, 3]
```

It works on Python `array.array`s the same way:

```
import array
x = array.array('d', [5, 2, 1, 10])
print(argsort(x))
# [2, 1, 0, 3]
```

Comment: Instead of using the (theoretically private) __getitem__, you can also use `operator.itemgetter` / `operator.attrgetter` http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html

Comment: If `operator.itemgetter` could be used as a drop-in replacement for `__getitem__`, I think I'd agreed with you Ender, but as far as I can see, `operator.itemgetter` would also require wrapping it in a `lambda` expression. I'd rather avoid the extra `lambda` if I could.

Comment: @Ender: `itemgetter` is no use here: `x.__getitem__(i)` returns `x[i]`, whereas `itemgetter(x)(i)` will return `i[x]`.

Comment: In my opinion, `key=lambda i: seq[i]` might be easier to understand.

Comment: agreed with comment above (`key=lambda i: seq[i]`) might be easier to read- but still great!

Answer (score 8):

My alternative with enumerate:

```
def argsort(seq):
    return [x for x,y in sorted(enumerate(seq), key = lambda x: x[1])]

seq=[5,2,1,10]
print(argsort(seq))
# Output:
# [2, 1, 0, 3]
```

Better though to use answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/9990/marcelo-cantos answer to thread [python sort without lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407414/python-sort-without-lambda-expressions)

```
[i for (v, i) in sorted((v, i) for (i, v) in enumerate(seq))]
```

Answer (score 4):

Found this question, but needed argsort for a list of objects based on an object property.

Extending unutbu's answer, this would be:

```
sorted(range(len(seq)), key = lambda x: seq[x].sort_property)
```