# python sort without lambda expressions

Tags: python, lambda, sorting

I often do sorts in Python using lambda expressions, and although it works fine, I find it not very readable, and was hoping there might be a better way.  Here is a typical use case for me.

I have a list of numbers, e.g., `x = [12, 101, 4, 56, ...]`

I have a separate list of indices: `y = range(len(x))`

I want to sort `y` based on the values in `x`, and I do this:

```
y.sort(key=lambda a: x[a])
```

Is there a good way to do this without using lambda?

Comment: Any particular reason why a sorted list of the original values wouldn't suffice? `x_sorted = sorted(x)`

Comment: The OP wants the indexes of the elements in sorted order, not the elements themselves.

Comment: It is a shame that `lambda` is such a long and ugly keyword.  This is pretty much the way to do it.

Comment: Looks very much similar than the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382352/equivalent-of-numpy-argsort-in-basic-python where I answered to give 'rank order list' solution, unfortunately with lambda. For me I prefer it though to the itemgetter solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `__getitem__` method of the list x.  This behaves the same as your lambda and will be much faster since it is implemented as a C function instead of a python function:

```
>>> x = [12, 101, 4, 56]
>>> y = range(len(x))
>>> sorted(y, key=x.__getitem__)
[2, 0, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 7):

Not elegantly, but:

```
[a for (v, a) in sorted((x[a], a) for a in y)]
```

BTW, you can do this without creating a separate list of indices:

```
[i for (v, i) in sorted((v, i) for (i, v) in enumerate(x))]
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is the kind of alternative you meant, but you could define the key function with a `def`:

```
def sort_key(value):
    return x[value]

y.sort(key = sort_key)
```

Personally, I think this is worse than the `lambda` as it moves the sort criteria away from the line of code doing the sort and it needlessly adds the `sort_key` function into your namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if I wanted to create another function, I could do it something like this (not tested):

```
def sortUsingList(indices, values):
    return indices[:].sort(key=lambda a: values[a])
```

Though I think I prefer to use lambda instead to avoid having to create an extra function.

Comment: You are using lambda against ther request (though I would use it myself).