# how to return index of a sorted list?

Tags: python

I need  to sort a list and then return a list with the index of the sorted items in the list. For example, if the list I want to sort is `[2,3,1,4,5]`, I need `[2,0,1,3,4]` to be returned.

This question was posted on bytes, but I thought I would repost it here.
http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/44513-sorting-list-then-return-index-sorted-item

My specific need to sort a list of objects based on a property of the objects. I then need to re-order a corresponding list to match the order of the newly sorted list.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: One option could be to map the list of objects to a list of tuples `[obj1, obj2, ...]` -> `[(0,obj1), (1, obj2), ...]` and sort this list. Then you have the new order of the original indexes right away.

Comment: You don't really need the indices to sort the corresponding list. Just zip the list together before sorting, then unzip. (Updated my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851077/how-to-return-index-of-a-sorted-list/7851186#7851186) with an example).

Comment: @FelixKling You'd need to do that, _and_ specify the sort key to be the second element of the tuple.

Comment: @sykora: Of course, but I thought OP is specifying a key anyway, as the objects are sorted by a certain property...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422700/how-to-get-indices-of-a-sorted-array-in-python

Comment: As someone doing numerical work I would be critical to the performance of list/zip/key trickery in Python, at least if the arrays are big. I think @jterrace offers the best solution.

Comment: Note the distinction between an `order` vector, in this case [2,0,1,3,4], and a `rank` vector, which would be [1,2,0,3,4]. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5284646

Answer (score 346, accepted):

You can use the python sorting functions' `key` parameter to sort the index array instead.

```
>>> s = [2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3]
>>> sorted(range(len(s)), key=lambda k: s[k])
[2, 0, 1, 5, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Comment: perhaps `key=s.__getitem__`?

Comment: If you need reverse order then use: sorted(range(len(s)), key=lambda k: s[k], reverse=True)

Comment: In case you also want the sorted array, `sorted_s = [s[k] for k in ind_s_to_sort]`, where **ind_s_to_sort** is the index acquired from this method.

Answer (score 96):

You can do this with numpy's [argsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy.argsort) method if you have numpy available:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> vals = numpy.array([2,3,1,4,5])
>>> vals
array([2, 3, 1, 4, 5])
>>> sort_index = numpy.argsort(vals)
>>> sort_index
array([2, 0, 1, 3, 4])
```

If not available, taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382352/equivalent-of-numpy-argsort-in-basic-python), this is the fastest method:

```
>>> vals = [2,3,1,4,5]
>>> sorted(range(len(vals)), key=vals.__getitem__)
[2, 0, 1, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Very nice. So the NumPy version is faster than the `sorted(...)` version?

Comment: For large arrays, yes.

Answer (score 24):

If you need both the sorted list and the list of indices, you could do:

```py
L = [2,3,1,4,5]
from operator import itemgetter
indices, L_sorted = zip(*sorted(enumerate(L), key=itemgetter(1)))
list(L_sorted)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list(indices)
>>> [2, 0, 1, 3, 4]
```

Or, for Python <2.4 (no `itemgetter` or `sorted`):

```py
temp = [(v,i) for i,v in enumerate(L)]
temp.sort
indices, L_sorted = zip(*temp)
```

p.s. The `zip(*iterable)` idiom reverses the zip process (unzip).

---

#### Update:

To deal with your specific requirements:

> "my specific need to sort a list of objects based on a property of the objects. i then need to re-order a corresponding list to match the order of the newly sorted list."

That's a long-winded way of doing it. You can achieve that with a single sort by zipping both lists together then sort using the object property as your sort key (and unzipping after).

```
combined = zip(obj_list, secondary_list)
zipped_sorted = sorted(combined, key=lambda x: x[0].some_obj_attribute)
obj_list, secondary_list = map(list, zip(*zipped_sorted))
```

Here's a simple example, using strings to represent your object. Here we use the length of the string as the key for sorting.:

```py
str_list = ["banana", "apple", "nom", "Eeeeeeeeeeek"]
sec_list = [0.123423, 9.231, 23, 10.11001]
temp = sorted(zip(str_list, sec_list), key=lambda x: len(x[0]))
str_list, sec_list = map(list, zip(*temp))
str_list
>>> ['nom', 'apple', 'banana', 'Eeeeeeeeeeek']
sec_list
>>> [23, 9.231, 0.123423, 10.11001]
```

Answer (score 9):

How about

```
l1 = [2,3,1,4,5]
l2 = [l1.index(x) for x in sorted(l1)]
```

Comment: This is `O(n^2)`...

Comment: This doesn't work for duplicates?

Comment: also see https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: This may be inefficient, but it is much more readable than the other answers, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `numpy.argsort`

or you can do:

```
test =  [2,3,1,4,5]
idxs = list(zip(*sorted([(val, i) for i, val in enumerate(test)])))[1]
```

`zip` will rearange the list so that the first element is `test` and the second is the `idxs`.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, looking at your specific need:

Say you have list `a` with some values, and your keys are in the attribute `x` of the objects stored in list `b`

```
keys = {i:j.x for i,j in zip(a, b)}
a.sort(key=keys.__get_item__)
```

With this method you get your list ordered without having to construct the intermediate permutation list you were asking for.

Answer (score -1):

Straight out of the documentation for `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
>>> # dictionary sorted by value
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3), ('apple', 4)])
```

Adapted to the example in the original post:

```
>>> l=[2,3,1,4,5]
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(enumerate(l), key=lambda x: x[1])).keys()
[2, 0, 1, 3, 4]
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict for details.