# Python: Sorting list in dictionary by key name

Tags: python

I have a dictionary object like below:

```
{'Role Name': ['Administrator'], 'Approval': ['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'], 'Functions': ['Transfer Amount', 'Withdraw Amount', 'Admin Action', 'Create Users', 'User Deletion'], 'Approve': ['N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N'], 'Action': ['N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y']}
```

I want to sort by Functions, so that the corresponding Approval, Approve and Action should also be sorted respectively. Show an example below:

```
{'Role Name': ['Administrator'], 'Approval': ['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'], 'Functions': ['Admin Action', 'Create Users', 'Transfer Amount', 'User Deletion', 'Withdraw Amount'], 'Approve': ['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y'], 'Action': ['Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y']}
```

Could someone please guide me?

Comment: But `Action` is not sorted, is it?

Comment: Sorry let me make it very clear. When I sort the Function, the corresponding value of the Approval, Approve and Action have to be positioned on their respective indices.
Ex: The value Transfer Amount is sorted and placed in 3rd index, so the respective Approval i.e., N, Approve - N and Action - N also should be positioned in 3rd index.
I hope it makes it very clear now.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has down voted. Isn't the correct question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort the other lists based on the order of `'Functions'`, and sort that list last. One way to implement this is using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to combine e.g. `'Functions'` and `'Action'` into a single list `[('Transfer Amount', 'N'), ...]`, sort that, then extract the second value from each pair (using e.g. [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)):

```
from operator import itemgetter

data = {'Role Name': ['Administrator'], 
        'Approval': ['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'], 
        'Functions': ['Transfer Amount', 'Withdraw Amount', 'Admin Action', 'Create Users', 'User Deletion'], 
        'Approve': ['N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N'], 
        'Action': ['N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y']}

for key in ['Action', 'Approval', 'Approve']:
    data[key] = map(itemgetter(1), sorted(zip(data['Functions'], data[key])))

data['Functions'] = sorted(data['Functions'])
```

This gives me the answer you're looking for:

```
{'Role Name': ['Administrator'], 
 'Approval': ['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'], 
 'Functions': ['Admin Action', 'Create Users', 'Transfer Amount', 'User Deletion', 'Withdraw Amount'], 
 'Approve': ['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y'], 
 'Action': ['Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y']}
```

Comment: Very nice and I like your explanation too. It is a new learning for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for you:
I removed the numpy dependency by using this technique [to get indices of a sorted list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851077/how-to-return-index-of-a-sorted-list)
We find the indices of the permutation to sort the `'Functions'`, then we apply this permutation to the keys all other than `'Role Name'`:

```
dictionary = {'Role Name': ['Administrator'],
 'Approval': ['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'],
 'Functions': ['Transfer Amount', 'Withdraw Amount', 'Admin Action', 'Create Users', 'User Deletion'],
 'Approve': ['N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N'],
 'Action': ['N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y']}

sorted_idx = sorted(range(len(dictionary['Functions'])), key=lambda k: dictionary['Functions'][k])
for key in dictionary:
    if not (key == 'Role Name'):
        dictionary[key] = [dictionary[key][idx] for idx in sorted_idx]
```

it returns

```
{'Action': ['Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y'],
'Approval': ['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'],
'Approve': ['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y'],
'Functions': ['Admin Action',
'Create Users',
'Transfer Amount',
'User Deletion',
'Withdraw Amount'],
'Role Name': ['Administrator']}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I cannot use numpy due to some restrictions in my environment.

Comment: @Vimal i removed the numpy dependency by using this approach to find the indices of a sorted list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851077/how-to-return-index-of-a-sorted-list instead of using numpy.argsort().