# Trying to sort three list of data so the sort order of each list is the same

Tags: python

I have a program that has three list off data called proffit,  macdHi and macdLow.
The macdHi and macdLo are the parmeters put into a function to create the price vales so

```
price[x]=f(macdHi]x],macdLow[x])
```

This list is very large and I would like to sort the lists so after I sort price, macdHi and macdLow list are sorted in the order.
I can use pythons sort method to sort the price list, but then the order of macdLo and macdHi list no longer match price list so 
     price[x]=f(macdHi]x],macdLow[x]) is no longer true

Comment: Zip them into a tuple, sort the tuple on price, then unzip...

Comment: you need the sort indices
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851077/how-to-return-index-of-a-sorted-list

Comment: Perhaps if those three values are associated, they should be in one object all the time.  A list of that object can be sorted on whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
AllLists = [macdHi,macdLow]

#sort by MacdHi
SortedByMacdHi = sorted(AllLists, key=lambda row: row[0])
for i in range(len(SortedByMacdHi)):
    price[i]=f(AllLists[0][i],AllLists[1][i])

#sort by MacdLow
SortedByMacdLow = sorted(AllLists, key=lambda row: row[1])
for i in range(len(SortedByMacdLow)):
    price[i]=f(AllLists[0][i],AllLists[1][i])

#sort by price
for i in range(len(macdHi)):
    price[i]=f(macdHi[i],macdLow[i])
CombinedList = [price,macdHi,macdLow]
SortedByMacdLow = sorted(CombinedList, key=lambda row: row[0])
```

I had no data to test with though. Basically the first two methods I combine macdHi and macdLow so I could sort them while keeping their rows corresponding. I would then use that sorted list to create price.

The 3rd method I did almost the same thing as the first two, but reversed the operation. I created price, then I combined the three lists so I could keep their rows corresponding during the sort.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) offers a much easier/faster/cleaner solution to this. It has built in methods for sorting data based on various criteria and is optimized for large data sets.

A good tutorial on this is available here: http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_sorting_rows_dataframe.html