# Python -- efficient way to obtain index of elements in sorted list, sorted with multiple attributes

Tags: python, list, sorting, indexing

I have a list of xyz-coordinates with the following format:

```
mycrds = [[0.0, 0.5, 0.1],
          [0.4, 0.6, 0.8],
          [0.2, 0.3, 0.9], ...]
```

I know that if I want to get the sorted list, sorted first by z, second by y, and last by x, I need to do:

```
sorted(mycrds, key=lambda x: [x[2], x[1], x[0]])
```

but how can I obtain the list of the original index of each coordinates in the sorted list? So far I have tried all the methods described in [how to return index of a sorted list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851077/how-to-return-index-of-a-sorted-list), but none of them worked well, except for the O(N^2) method. I'm wondering if there is any efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l2 = list(enumerate(mycrds))
sorted(l2, key=lambda x: [x[1][2], x[1][1], x[1][0]])
print(l2)
```

Enumerate will preserve the original coordinates of the array.

Comment: This does it. If you want the keys as a lone array: `list(map(lambda x: x[0], sorted(enumerate(mycrds), key=lambda x: [x[1][2], x[1][1], x[1][0]])))` might help.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
mycrds = [[0.0, 0.5, 0.9],
          [0.4, 0.6, 0.8],
          [0.2, 0.3, 0.1]]
```

If this gives you the sort order you want:

```
>>> sorted(mycrds, key=lambda sl: (sl[2],sl[1],sl[0]))
[[0.2, 0.3, 0.1], [0.4, 0.6, 0.8], [0.0, 0.5, 0.9]]
```

Then you can get the original index of each list item like so:

```
>>> sorted(range(len(mycrds)), key=lambda i: (mycrds[i][2],mycrds[i][1],mycrds[i][0]))
[2, 1, 0]
```

So all you doing is sorting a range from `0..len(your_list)` and using that index, `i`, to refer to the element in the list and form the sort tuple the same way. This will be the same complexity as sorting the underlying list.