# Adding values from for-loop into an array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the length of the values of the states array into a separate array then sort them by descending order, but I'm having trouble getting all the length values of the string into the array instead of having a single value after the iteration.

```
states = ["Abia", "Adamawa", "Anambra", "Akwa Ibom", "Bauchi", "Bayelsa", "Benue", "Borno", "Cross River", "Delta", "Ebonyi", "Enugu", "Edo", "Ekiti", "Gombe", "Imo", "Jigawa", "Kaduna", "Kano", "Katsina", "Kebbi", "Kogi", "Kwara", "Lagos", "Nasarawa", "Niger", "Ogun", "Ondo", "Osun", "Oyo", "Plateau", "Rivers", "Sokoto", "Taraba", "Yobe", "Zamfara"]

for i in states:
    a = [len(i)]
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want the lengths sorted in descending order, use `sorted` with `reverse=True` and list comprehension

```
states = ["Abia", "Adamawa", "Anambra", "Akwa Ibom", "Bauchi", "Bayelsa", "Benue", "Borno", "Cross River", "Delta", "Ebonyi", "Enugu", "Edo", "Ekiti", "Gombe", "Imo", "Jigawa", "Kaduna", "Kano", "Katsina", "Kebbi", "Kogi", "Kwara", "Lagos", "Nasarawa", "Niger", "Ogun", "Ondo", "Osun", "Oyo", "Plateau", "Rivers", "Sokoto", "Taraba", "Yobe", "Zamfara"]
a = sorted([len(i) for i in states], reverse=True)
print (a)
```

**Output**

```
[11, 9, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3]
```

To get the indices of the sorted list without resorting to `NumPy` arrays, there are many ways: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851077/how-to-return-index-of-a-sorted-list). I personally prefer to directly make use of `NumPy`'s `argsort`. As the name suggests, it returns an array of indices corresponding to the sorted array/list in ascending order. To get the indices for descending order, you can just reverse the array returned by `argsort` by using `[::-1]`. Following is a solution to your problem:

```
import numpy as np
states = ["Abia", "Adamawa", "Anambra", "Akwa Ibom", "Bauchi", "Bayelsa", "Benue", "Borno", "Cross River", "Delta", "Ebonyi", "Enugu", "Edo", "Ekiti", "Gombe", "Imo", "Jigawa", "Kaduna", "Kano", "Katsina", "Kebbi", "Kogi", "Kwara", "Lagos", "Nasarawa", "Niger", "Ogun", "Ondo", "Osun", "Oyo", "Plateau", "Rivers", "Sokoto", "Taraba", "Yobe", "Zamfara"]
a = [len(i) for i in states]
indices_sorted = np.argsort(a)[::-1] # [::-1] gives you indices for decreasing order
```

**Output**

```
array([ 8,  3, 24, 35, 19,  1,  2, 30,  5,  4, 10, 16, 17, 33, 32, 31, 22,
   13,  6,  7,  9, 11, 14, 25, 23, 20, 21, 26, 27, 34, 28, 18,  0, 12,
   15, 29])
```

Now as you can see, the first index in the above output is `8` which means the 9th element of `states` which is `Cross River`. Similarly you can access and verify the other elements.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying out the bubble sort to try and sort them but this is much easier.

Comment: Is there a way to create an index which will point out what number belongs to which name in the state list. Like for example, the first 7 could refer to the state "Adamawa".

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
lengths = [len(state) for state in states]
```

---

If you need to use a for loop, create a list and append to it:

```
lengths = []
for i in states:
    lengths.append(len(i))
```

Comment: I'm a beginner still learning so pardon my question, but where should I put that in my code?

Comment: That would replace the `for` loop

Comment: aah I get it now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using the [`map`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map) function without using a `for` loop:

```
a = list(map(len,states))
```

Answer (score 0):

Through generator:

```
lens = [len(a) for a in states]
```