# how to return the order index of each element of a list?

Tags: python, sorting, indexing

I have a list of Numbers, say `L=[50, 10, 30]`, and in Python I want to return a list giving the order index of each element in `L`, which would be this output: `[2, 0, 1]`.

Though it seems to be a simple task, many questions on this site ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7851166/3871924) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6422700/3871924) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6979121/3871924) for instance) focus on the other way round, meaning the index from the *sorted list* point of view: `[1, 2, 0]`, which is not what I want.

Thanks,

**EDIT:** about repetitions, i'd like them to be counted as well (draws taken in order of appearance). `[50,30,10,30]` would give `[3,1,0,2]`

Comment: What do you expect to happen when there are repetitions of a number in the list? Say the lowest number `10` is repeated twice, do you expect the output to show two `[0,0]` followed by a `2` instead of `1`?

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla I edited..thanks for this remark

Comment: Isn't this question duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12486822/1586200)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One liner:

```
l = [50, 30, 10, 30]
numpy.argsort(numpy.argsort(l))
# array([3, 1, 0, 2])
```

Comment: I knew `np.argsort` would work, but didn't know how :-)

Answer (score 3):

it is the index list of the sorted order:

```
def sort_order(lst):
    orders = sorted(list(range(len(lst))), key=lambda x: lst[x])
    ret = [0] * len(lst)
    for i in range(len(ret)):
        ret[orders[i]] = i
    return ret

print(sort_order([50, 10, 30]) # [2,0,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Enumerating and sorting twice like:

```
L = [50, 10, 30]
x = tuple(k[1] for k in sorted((x[1], j) for j, x in enumerate(
    sorted((x, i) for i, x in enumerate(L)))))
print(x)
```

#### Results:

```
(2, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Using dicts..

```
L = [50, 10, 30, 10, 30]
d = {counter:value for counter,value in enumerate(L)} #L is your list
sorteddict = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
d2 = {counter:value for counter,value in enumerate(sorteddict)}
order_index = {d2[i][0]:i for i in d2}
print(order_index.values())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the output of your solution is not the same as my desired output (that might be the reason of the downvote ) Marc

Comment: Good point. I misunderstood the question. Edited with the correct code.