# Get list of indices in case you sort a list in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to know the new index for a given element in a list after sorting.

The same question was asked for python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851077/how-to-return-index-of-a-sorted-list), but I like to do this in Javascript.

So basically the input to a function is a list [1,3,2] and then the output should be [0,2,1].

Comment: You haven't specified much of a question. Can you elaborate, including what you've attempted and/or where you're having difficulty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the indices of the data array and sort the indices by the values of the data array. As result you get an array of sorted indices.

If necessary map the indices and the appropriate value for a sorted data array.

```js
var data = [1, 3, 2],
    indices = [...data.keys()];

indices.sort((a, b) => data[a] - data[b]);
data = indices.map(i => data[i]);

console.log(...indices);
console.log(...data);
```