# My while loop runs infinite times when I think its not supposed to

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I was trying write a code that gives index of a minimum value of list one after other
For example:

```
if list=[2,4,1,2,5]
         0 1 2 3 4
```

output:

> [2,0,3,1,4]--> where each element in this corresponds to index of list
> variable

```
import math
list=[2,4,1,2,5]
a=[]
i=0
while(i <= (len(list)-1)):
    if(list[i]==min(list)):
        a.append(i)
        list[i]=math.inf
        i=-1
    i+=1

print(a)
```

Comment: Refer to this [page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-returning-index-of-a-sorted-list/).

Comment: `sorted(range(len(list)), key=lambda x: list[x])`. Which is from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851077/how-to-return-index-of-a-sorted-list

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, when `list` becomes all `inf`, `list[i]==min(list)` is true because both `list[i]` and `min(list)` are `inf`.  Then `i` resets to zero and you're in an infinite loop.

```
print(list, i, list[i], min(list), a)
```

Outputs:

```
[inf, inf, inf, inf, inf] 0 inf inf [2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

You can see that list `a` is being appended with zeroes.

"List" is actually a keyword in Python.  Yes, it lets you use it, but that's bad form and you should use something like "lyst" or just "x" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use 'list' to define your list. Use something else like 'my_list'.

you can use `numpy` library to generate an index of a minimum value of a list.

```py
import numpy as np 

my_list = [2,4,1,2,5]
minimum_value_index = [np.argsort(my_list)[x] for x in range(len(my_list))]

print(minimum_value_index)
```

This will output as following:

```
[2, 0, 3, 1, 4]
```

Hope this helps.