# Convert list of N items to relative ordering (0-(N-1))?

Tags: python, algorithm, list

For example if I have a list of distinct items:

```
L = [100,55,104,400]
```

The "relative" orderings can be restated:

```
R = [1,0,2,3]
```

I am not sure how to convert L to R. At first I just tried subtracting min(L) from everything but that doesn't "compress" things down to relative order.

I am looking for an efficient solution (not O(n<sup>2</sup>)).

Comment: You can also check the other dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382352/equivalent-of-numpy-argsort-in-basic-python

Comment: This is pretty simple if you know your basic built-in functions: `[i for i, x in sorted(enumerate(L), key=itemgetter(1))]` You can get `itemgetter` from the `operator` module.

Comment: This is a bad example. A better example would be `[100,104,55,400]`; should that give `[1,2,0,3]` or `[2,0,1,3]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a combination of list comprehension,  `zip`, and `sorted`:

```
>>> [i[1] for i in sorted(zip(L, range(4)))]
[1, 0, 2, 3]
```

This is O(nlogn) since you only need to sort once.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function and a list comprehension.

```
>>> l =  [100,55,104,400]
>>> sortedl = sorted(l)
>>> [sortedl.index(i) for i in l]
[1, 0, 2, 3]
```

Note that this is O(n<sup>2</sup>) <sub><sub>Answered before edit to ques</sub></sub>

Comment: Nice and elegant, but please note that if list becomes large, this solution becomes inefficient (as I recall, each index() will be O(n), making this solution O(n^2))

Comment: @amit That is the other problem I have been running into when using list comprehensions

Comment: @user4967499 If you are looking for an efficient solution you should also mention it...

Comment: @amit Added qualifier

Answer (score 1):

Simple list comprehension:

```
>>> L = [100, 55, 104, 400]
>>> R = [L.index(i) for i in sorted(L)]
[1, 0, 2, 3]
```