# Trying to improve efficiency of this search in an array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, stl

Suppose I have an input array where all objects are non-equivalent - e.g. [13,2,36]. I want the output array to be [1,0,2], since 13 is greater than 2 so "1", 2 is greater than no element so "0", 36 is greater than both 13 and 2 so "2". How do I get the output array with efficiency better than O(n2)?
Edit 1 : I also want to print the output in same ordering. Give a c/c++ code if possible.

Comment: What should the output be for `[13, 13, 2, 36]`?

Comment: Not exactly a dupe, but you can see my answer there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655250/convert-list-of-n-items-to-relative-ordering-0-n-1/30655277#30655277

Comment: sounds like homework

Comment: @Kevin very good question! My inclination is [1,1,0,2] but who knows if it should be [2,1,0,3] instead! LTR

Comment: You can get an output of the array with efficiency better than O(n2) by using a good framework from github that handles sorting ;)

Comment: @Kevin Considering all the elements are distinct.

Comment: i want to use it in a c/c++ code + I also have to print the output in the same ordering.

Comment: `[13, 36, 2]` makes for a better example. It's easy to misread the problem in a way that gives the right answer for your sample input data.

Comment: @user3518381 i have posted a solution.Check if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a dynamic programming.
May be this can help 
Here is an O(n) algorithm

**1.Declare an array of say max size say 1000001;**

**2.Traverse through all the elements and make arr[input[n]]=1 where input[n] is the element**

**3.Traverse through the arr and add with the previous index(To keep record of arr[i] is greater than how many elements) like this**

```
  arr[i]+=arr[i-1]
```

Example: if input[]={12,3,36}
After step 2
arr[12]=1,arr[3]=1,arr[36]=1;
After step 3
arr[3]=1,arr[4]=arr[3]+arr[4]=1(arr[4]=0,arr[3]=1),
arr[11]=arr[10]=arr[9]=arr[8]=arr[7]arr[6]=arr[5]=arr[4]=1
arr[12]=arr[11]+arr[12]=2(arr[11]=1,arr[12]=1)
arr[36]=arr[35]+arr[36]=3(because arr[13],arr[14],...arr[35]=2 and arr[36]=1)

**4.Traverse through the input array an print `arr[input[i]]-1` where i is the index.**

So arr[3]=1,arr[12]=2,arr[36]=3;
If you print arr[input[i]] then output will be {2,1,3} so we need to subtract 1 from each element then the output becomes {1,0,2}  which is your desired output.

//pseude code

```
int arr[1000001];
int input[size];//size is the size of the input array
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
     input[i]=take input;//take input
     arr[input[i]]=1;//setting the index of input[i]=1; 
for(i=1;i<1000001;i++)
     arr[i]+=arr[i-1];

for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    print arr[input[i]]-1;//since arr[i] was initialized with 1 but you want the input as 0 for first element(so subtracting 1 from each element)
```

To understand the algorithm better,take paper and pen and do the dry run.It will help to understand better.

Hope it helps
Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Clone original array (and keep original indexes of elements somewhere) and quicksort it. Value of the element in quicksorted array should be `quicksorted.length - i`, where `i` is index of element in the new quicksorted array.

```
[13, 2, 36] - original
[36(2), 13(1), 2(0)] - sorted
[1, 0, 2] - substituted
```

Comment: How do I substitute it?

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort(array):
    temp = sorted(array)
    indexDict = {temp[i]: i for i in xrange(len(temp))}
    return [indexDict[i] for i in array]
```

I realize it's in python, but nevertheless should still help you

Answer (score 0):

Schwartzian transform: decorate, sort, undecorate.

Create a structure holding an object as well as an index.  Create a new list of these structures from your list.  Sort by the objects as planned.  Create a list of the indices from the sorted list.