# Indices of the permutation for sorted list

Tags: python

Given an array, I would like to get an array holding the indices of the permutation that would result in the array being sorted. An example should make it clear:
Input array:

```
[10, 50, 40, 20, 30]
```

should produce the following output:

```
[0, 3, 4, 2, 1]
```

because if I first take the 0th, then the 3rd, then the 4th, then the 2nd and then the 1st element of the list, I would get `[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]`, which would be the sorted array.

Of course I could just code it in Python from scratch, but I wonder if there is a function for this in Python already.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent of Numpy.argsort() in basic python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382352/equivalent-of-numpy-argsort-in-basic-python)

Comment: not immediately, but following the links to other questions from there did in the end; thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use [NumPy argsort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html): that provides exactly what you need.

```
a = np.array([10, 50, 40, 20, 30])
np.argsort(a)
```

will result in

```
np.array([0, 3, 4, 2, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [10, 50, 40, 20, 30]
ix = [a.index(v) for v in sorted(a)]
```

To my knowledge, there is no function for this. Just this half liner.

Comment: Try this with `a = [10, 50, 40, 20, 30, 10]`.