# Return order of NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I'm trying to return an array which has the rank of each value in an array. For example, given the array below:

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([4, 5, 3, 1])
```

I would want to return the array:

```
array([2, 3, 1, 0])
```

Such that the values in the returned array indicate the ascending order of the array (ie, the value in the returned array indicates which is largest). Using argsort, I can only tell how the values should be reordered:

```
arr1.argsort()
array([3, 2, 0, 1])
```

Let me know if this is unclear.

Comment: Are you sure you want [2,3,0,1] and not [2,3,1,0]?

Comment: I do not understand how you arrive at `array([2, 3, 0, 1])` from your description.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rank items in an array using Python/NumPy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284646/rank-items-in-an-array-using-python-numpy)

Comment: Thank for checking into this, I found a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284646/rank-items-in-an-array-using-python-numpy

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There might be a better way but I've allways done `argsort().argsort()`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.random(5)
>>> a
array([ 0.54254555,  0.4547267 ,  0.50008037,  0.20388227,  0.13725801])
>>> a.argsort().argsort()
array([4, 2, 3, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that [2,3,0,1] is a typo for [2,3,1,0], you could use [lexsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html#numpy-lexsort):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr1 = np.array([4,5,3,1])
>>> np.lexsort((np.arange(len(arr1)), arr1.argsort()))
array([2, 3, 1, 0])
```