# Ranking data in python without numpy

Tags: python, arrays, list

Is there a way in python (without numpy) to rank lists?
for example:

```
array1 = [1934,1232,345453,123423423,23423423,23423421]
array = [4,2,7,1,1,2]
ranks = [2,1,3,0,0,1]
```

[Gives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284646/rank-items-in-an-array-using-python-numpy) me examples only with numpy.

I would primarily like to rank the data and then process the data based on ranks to see which dataelements in array1 contribute to 90% of the highest data in array.

Let me know if you want me to give an example.

Comment: Please give examples on how `array1` and `array` are converted to `ranks`

Comment: If you're going to be mathing, numpy's probably your best bet. Obviously you can reimplement any algorithm you want in pure python, but I can't think of any non-didactic reason to do so.

Comment: I don't know how to convert them to ranks without numpy.

Comment: @pistal How do you normally convert them to ranks? Is there any formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can build a rank dictionary easily enough, and then loop over the elements of `array` to find the ranks:

```
>>> array = [4,2,7,1,1,2]
>>> rankdict = {v: k for k,v in enumerate(sorted(set(array)))}
>>> rankdict
{1: 0, 2: 1, 4: 2, 7: 3}
>>> ranked = [rankdict[a] for a in array]
>>> ranked
[2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1]
```

---

If you want to sort `array1` by this ranking, there are several ways to do it.  One common one is to build a zipped list and then sort that:

```
>>> zip(ranked, array)
[(2, 4), (1, 2), (3, 7), (0, 1), (0, 1), (1, 2)]
>>> sorted(zip(ranked, array))
[(0, 1), (0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 7)]
>>> sorted(zip(ranked, array1))
[(0, 23423423), (0, 123423423), (1, 1232), (1, 23423421), (2, 1934), (3, 345453)]
```

Comment: How do we sort the ranked list and then sort the array1 corresponding to it?

Comment: and how do we get the top 90% of the data in array? should i sum thru the list and search for 90% and kick the rest out (based on ranks)?

Comment: @pistal: there are several ways you could define "top 90%"; choose one and try something.

Comment: Would you suggest running thru the list and searching for top 90%? that's something that strikes me right now.