# How to get the index of the sorted list for the original list in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

The `argsort` function of numpy returns the original index of the sorted list. 
Now I want the index of the sorted list for the original list. Is there 
a function or an elegant way to do this ?

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([2, 8 , 5, 6])
>>> np.argsort(a)
array([0, 2, 3, 1])
>>> function(a)
array([0, 3, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could always call `argsort` twice:

```
>>> a.argsort().argsort()
array([0, 3, 1, 2])
```

As far as I know, there's no "double-argsort" function available in NumPy, but applying `argsort` twice to an array is a common way to calculate the ranks of the values (cf. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284646/rank-items-in-an-array-using-python-numpy)).

Comment: how a wise solution !

Answer (score 7):

While the double `argsort` trick works, it is not very efficient. You can get better performance by using fancy indexing:

```
>>> argsort = a.argsort()
>>> rev_argsort = np.empty(argsort.shape, dtype=np.intp)
>>> rev_argsort[argsort] = np.arange(len(a))
>>> rev_argsort
array([0, 3, 1, 2])
```

It is more verbose, but it has linear complexity instead of the linearithmic complexity of `argsort`. In practice this means that, for sufficiently large arrays, the above code will run twice as fast as a double `argsort`, as the time to create and fill `rev_argsort` will be negligible against that of the first `argsort`.

Comment: I agree. Using assignment instead of sorting is a more reasonable solution. Thanks for pointing it out!