# Find IDs (or indices) of a np array in the sorted array, with possible repetitive elements

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, np.argsort

I have a 1D numpy array

```
x=np.array([0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.4])
```

I need to calculate another array of the same size, where each    element is the ID (or called index) in the sorted array. Here the sorted array would be [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]. Thus, 0.1 corresponds to ID 0; 0.2 corresponds to ID 1;...0.5 corresponds to ID 4. The expected result will be

```
    [0,2,1,3,4,3]
```

Note that this question is similar to, but different from [How to get the index of the sorted list for the original list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573545/how-to-get-the-index-of-the-sorted-list-for-the-original-list-in-python)
as we need to deal with repetitive elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
uniques, out = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
```

Output (`out`):

```
array([0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3])
```

That said, working with unique floats should generally be avoided.

Comment: I accepted this one because it seems to be more efficient than the one proposed by mathfux (which is very nice too).

Answer (score 1):

Try: [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
>>> x = np.array([0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.4])
>>> np.searchsorted(np.unique(x), x)
array([0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3], dtype=int32)
```

[`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) outputs unique items in sorted order.

Comment: but how do you get `np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5])`?

Comment: Ah, good point. A was considering this is a separate array. Alright, I can replace it with a `np.unique` of input array.

Comment: This was what I originally thought of. But then I realized `np.unique` has `return_inverse=True` :-)

Answer (score -1):

Just use

```py
import numpy as np
x=np.array([0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.4])
>>> indeces=np.argsort(x)
>>> indeces
array([0, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4])
```

Comment: No, this is not what OP's asking for.