# numpy.argsort gives results with random order

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I am trying to simply sort an array or a list using `numpy.argsort()`. For some reason, it is giving me results in random order:

```
import numpy

unsorted_list = [1.19021287, 1.19021287, 1.15190644, 1.12193492, 1.19021287, 1.25190644]
sorted_list = numpy.argsort(unsorted_list)
print sorted_list
array([3, 2, 0, 1, 4, 5])
```

It should return `array([0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 4])`

Comment: Why do you think 4 would show up in the result twice?

Comment: The smallest value in your list is `1.12...`.  It occurs at index 3, so the first value in the array returned by `argsort` is 3.  The next smallest value is `1.15...`, at index 2,  etc.  "Randomness" (more accurately "behavior that is hard to predict") might occur with values that are equal.  You can get more predictable behavior for those cases by using `kind='mergesort'`.

Comment: I don't understand how you determined the array that it "should" return, but if what you are really trying to do is *rank* the values, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284646/rank-items-in-an-array-using-python-numpy

Answer (score 5):

Well what does [`numpy.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) do?

> `numpy.argsort(a, axis=-1, kind='quicksort', order=None)`
>
> Returns the ***indices*** that would sort an array.
>
> Perform an indirect sort along the given axis using the algorithm specified by the `kind` keyword. It returns an array of indices of the same shape as `a` that index data along the given axis in sorted order.

So it gave you the **indices** which would sort the array, from smallest values in the array to largest. For your given array these are:

```
[3, 2, 0, 1, 4, 5]
```

Corresponding to the values:

```
3 -> 1.12193492
2 -> 1.15190644
0 -> 1.19021287
1 -> 1.19021287
4 -> 1.19021287
5 -> 1.25190644
```

So, adding a trailing `0` for example, would result in the following indices returned:

```
[6 3 2 0 1 4 5]
```