# How to display custom values on a bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I'm looking to see how to do two things in Seaborn with using a bar chart to display values that are in the dataframe, but not in the graph.

1. I'm looking to display the values of one field in a dataframe while graphing another.  For example, below, I'm graphing 'tip', but I would like to place the value of `'total_bill'` centered above each of the bars (i.e.325.88 above Friday, 1778.40 above Saturday, etc.)
2. Is there a way to scale the colors of the bars, with the lowest value of `'total_bill'` having the lightest color (in this case Friday) and the highest value of `'total_bill'` having the darkest?  Obviously, I'd stick with one color (i.e., **blue**) when I do the scaling.

While I see that others think that this is a duplicate of another problem (or two), I am missing the part of how I use a value that is not in the graph as the basis for the label or the shading.  How do I say, use total_bill as the basis.  I'm sorry, but I just can't figure it out based on those answers.

Starting with the following code,

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/1st-edition/ch08/tips.csv", sep=',')
groupedvalues = df.groupby('day').sum().reset_index()
g = sns.barplot(x='day', y='tip', data=groupedvalues)
```

I get the following result:

[image]

Interim Solution:

```
for index, row in groupedvalues.iterrows():
    g.text(row.name, row.tip, round(row.total_bill, 2), color='black', ha="center")
```

[image]

On the ***shading***, using the example below, I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/1st-edition/ch08/tips.csv", sep=',')
groupedvalues = df.groupby('day').sum().reset_index()

pal = sns.color_palette("Greens_d", len(data))
rank = groupedvalues.argsort().argsort()
g = sns.barplot(x='day', y='tip', data=groupedvalues)

for index, row in groupedvalues.iterrows():
    g.text(row.name, row.tip, round(row.total_bill, 2), color='black', ha="center")
```

But that gave me the following error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'argsort'

So I tried a modification:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/1st-edition/ch08/tips.csv", sep=',')
groupedvalues = df.groupby('day').sum().reset_index()

pal = sns.color_palette("Greens_d", len(data))
rank = groupedvalues['total_bill'].rank(ascending=True)
g = sns.barplot(x='day', y='tip', data=groupedvalues, palette=np.array(pal[::-1])[rank])
```

and that leaves me with

> IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4

Comment: This question is not a duplicate because it's trying to annotate with **different values than those plotted**. While similarly labeling the bar as shown in [How to add value labels on a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28931224/7758804), the extra step of using different values is required.

Comment: This is the subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419183/should-we-drastically-change-titles-on-highly-viewed-voted-questions).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Stick to the solution from [Changing color scale in seaborn bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271302/changing-color-scale-in-seaborn-bar-plot), which uses `argsort` to determine the order of the bar colors. In the linked question, `argsort` is applied to a `Series` object, while here you have a `DataFrame`. Select one column of the `DataFrame` to apply `argsort` on.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
groupedvalues = df.groupby('day').sum().reset_index()

pal = sns.color_palette('Greens_d', len(groupedvalues))
rank = groupedvalues['total_bill'].argsort().argsort() 
g = sns.barplot(x='day', y='tip', data=groupedvalues, palette=np.array(pal[::-1])[rank])

for index, row in groupedvalues.iterrows():
    g.text(row.name, row.tip, round(row.total_bill, 2), color='black', ha='center')
    
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

The second attempt works fine as well, the only issue is the rank, as returned by `rank()`, starts at `1` instead of `0`. So one has to subtract `1` from the array. For indexing, we need integer values, so cast it to `int`.

```
rank = groupedvalues['total_bill'].rank(ascending=True).values
rank = (rank-1).astype(int)
```

---

- From `matplotlib 3.4.0`, there is [`.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html), which has a `label` parameter for custom labels.

  - Other answers using `.bar_label` didn't customize the labels with `labels=`.
  - See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) from May 16, 2021, for a thorough explanation of `.bar_label` with links to documentation and examples.

1. The `day` column downloads as a `category Dtype`, which keeps the days of the week in order. This also ensures the plot order of the bars on the x-axis and the values in `tb`.

   - `.bar_label` adds labels from left to right, so the values in `tb` are in the same order as the bars.
   - If working with a column that isn't categorical, [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) can be used on the column to set the order.

- In [`sns.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html), `estimator=sum` is specified to sum `tip`. The default is `mean`.

```py
df = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# sum total_bill by day
tb = df.groupby('day').total_bill.sum()

# get the colors in blues as requested
pal = sns.color_palette("Blues_r", len(tb))

# rank the total_bill sums
rank = tb.argsort()

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
sns.barplot(x='day', y='tip', data=df, palette=np.array(pal[::-1])[rank], estimator=sum, ci=False, ax=ax)

# 1. add labels using bar_label with custom labels from tb
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels=tb, padding=3)

# pad the spacing between the number and the edge of the figure
ax.margins(y=0.1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 150):

### New in matplotlib 3.4.0

- There is now a built-in [`Axes.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html) to automatically label bar containers:

  ```py
  ax = sns.barplot(x='day', y='tip', data=groupedvalues)
  ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0]) # only 1 container needed unless using `hue`
  ```

  [image: seaborn bar plot labeled]
- For **custom labels** (e.g., `tip` bars with `total_bill` values), use the `labels` parameter:

  ```py
  ax = sns.barplot(x='day', y='tip', data=groupedvalues)
  ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels=groupedvalues['total_bill'])
  #                              ----------------------------------
  ```

  [image: seaborn bar plot custom values]
- For **multi-group** bar plots (i.e., with `hue`), there will be multiple bar containers that need to be iterated:

  ```py
  ax = sns.barplot(x='day', y='tip', hue='sex', data=df)
  for container in ax.containers:
      ax.bar_label(container)
  ```

  [image: seaborn grouped bar plot labeled]

More details:

- [How to label percentage counts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68322925/13138364) (`fmt` param)
- [How to rotate labels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71261629/13138364) (`rotation` param)
- [How to vertically center labels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70860248/13138364) (`label_type` param)
- [How to add spacing to labels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71012052/13138364) (`padding` param)

---

### Color-ranked version

> Is there a way to scale the colors of the bars, with the lowest value of `total_bill` having the lightest color (in this case Friday) and the highest value of `total_bill` having the darkest?

1. Find the rank of each `total_bill` value:

   - Either use [`Series.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html):

     ```py
     ranks = groupedvalues.total_bill.sort_values().index
     # Int64Index([1, 0, 3, 2], dtype='int64')
     ```
   - Or condense Ernest's [`Series.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) version by chaining [`Series.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html):

     ```py
     ranks = groupedvalues.total_bill.rank().sub(1).astype(int).array
     # [1, 0, 3, 2]
     ```
2. Then reindex the color palette using `ranks`:

   ```py
   palette = sns.color_palette('Blues_d', len(ranks))
   ax = sns.barplot(x='day', y='tip', palette=np.array(palette)[ranks], data=groupedvalues)
   ```

   [image: seaborn bar plot color-ranked]

Answer (score 71):

This works with a single ax or with a matrix of ax (subplots):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def show_values_on_bars(axs):
    def _show_on_single_plot(ax):
        for p in ax.patches:
            _x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2
            _y = p.get_y() + p.get_height()
            value = '{:.2f}'.format(p.get_height())
            ax.text(_x, _y, value, ha="center")

    if isinstance(axs, np.ndarray):
        for idx, ax in np.ndenumerate(axs):
            _show_on_single_plot(ax)
    else:
        _show_on_single_plot(axs)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
show_values_on_bars(ax)
```

Answer (score 52):

Just in case if anyone is interested in labeling **horizontal barplot graph**, I modified [Sharon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51535326/7898385) as below:

```
def show_values_on_bars(axs, h_v="v", space=0.4):
    def _show_on_single_plot(ax):
        if h_v == "v":
            for p in ax.patches:
                _x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2
                _y = p.get_y() + p.get_height()
                value = int(p.get_height())
                ax.text(_x, _y, value, ha="center") 
        elif h_v == "h":
            for p in ax.patches:
                _x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() + float(space)
                _y = p.get_y() + p.get_height()
                value = int(p.get_width())
                ax.text(_x, _y, value, ha="left")

    if isinstance(axs, np.ndarray):
        for idx, ax in np.ndenumerate(axs):
            _show_on_single_plot(ax)
    else:
        _show_on_single_plot(axs)
```

**Two parameters explained:**

`h_v` - Whether the barplot is horizontal or vertical. `"h"` represents the horizontal barplot, `"v"` represents the vertical barplot.

`space` - The space between value text and the top edge of the bar. Only works for horizontal mode.

**Example:**

```
show_values_on_bars(sns_t, "h", 0.3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
graph = sns.barplot(x='name_column_x_axis', y="name_column_x_axis", data=dataframe_name, color="salmon")
for p in graph.patches:
    graph.annotate('{:.0f}'.format(p.get_height()),
                   (p.get_x() + 0.3, p.get_height()),
                   ha='center',
                   va='bottom',
                   color='black')
```

Answer (score 4):

I hope this helps for item #2:

a) You can sort by total bill and then reset the index to this column 
b) Use palette="Blue" to use this color to scale your chart from light blue to dark blue (if dark blue to light blue then use palette="Blues_d")

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/master/ch08/tips.csv", sep=',')
groupedvalues = df.groupby('day').sum().reset_index()
groupedvalues = groupedvalues.sort_values('total_bill').reset_index()
g = sns.barplot(x='day', y='tip', data=groupedvalues, palette="Blues")
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to do so is to add the below code (for Seaborn):

```
for p in splot.patches:
    splot.annotate(format(p.get_height(), '.1f'),
                   (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),
                   ha = 'center', va = 'center',
                   xytext = (0, 9),
                   textcoords = 'offset points')
```

Example:

```
splot = sns.barplot(df['X'], df['Y'])
# Annotate the bars in plot
for p in splot.patches:
    splot.annotate(format(p.get_height(), '.1f'),
                   (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),
                   ha = 'center', va = 'center',
                   xytext = (0, 9),
                   textcoords = 'offset points')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import seaborn as sns

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12, 8))
ax = plt.subplot(111)

ax = sns.barplot(x="Knowledge_type", y="Percentage", hue="Distance", data=knowledge)

for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(format(p.get_height(), '.2f'), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()), 
       ha = 'center', va = 'center', xytext = (0, 10), textcoords = 'offset points')
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67620768/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).