# Seaborn workaround for hue barplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I have the following DataFrame on a **Jupyter notebook** which plots using seaborn a barplot:

```
data = {'day_index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        'avg_duration': [708.852242, 676.7021900000001, 684.572677, 708.92534, 781.767476, 1626.575057, 1729.155673],
        'trips': [114586, 120936, 118882, 117868, 108036, 43740, 37508]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

daysOfWeek = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

plt.figure(figsize=(16,10));
sns.set_style('ticks')
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, \
                 x='day_index', \
                 y='avg_duration', \
                 hue='trips', \
                 palette=sns.color_palette("Reds_d", n_colors=7, desat=1))

ax.set_xlabel("Week Days", fontsize=18, alpha=0.8)
ax.set_ylabel("Duration (seconds)", fontsize=18, alpha=0.8)
ax.set_title("Week's average Trip Duration", fontsize=24)
ax.set_xticklabels(daysOfWeek, fontsize=16)
ax.legend(fontsize=15)
sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

**Plot A:**
[image]

As it can be seen the bars do not match the x_ticklabels and are very thin.
This is all fixed if I remove the `hue='trips'` part, it's a known seaborn issue.
Although It's very important to show the amount of trips in the visualization so: **is there a way around seaborn (maybe with matplotlib directly) to add a hue attribute?**

Comment: Note that you can use `sns.barplot(..., hue='trips', dodge=False)` to have bars with normal widths.  By default, `dodge=True` to prevent multiple bars with the same x from overlapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't need to specify `hue` parameter in this case:

```
In [136]: ax = sns.barplot(data=dfGroupedAgg, \
     ...:                  x='day_index', \
     ...:                  y='avg_duration', \
     ...:                  palette=sns.color_palette("Reds_d", n_colors=7, desat=1))
     ...:
```

you can add amount of trips as annotations:

```
def autolabel(rects, labels=None, height_factor=1.05):
    for i, rect in enumerate(rects):
        height = rect.get_height()
        if labels is not None:
            try:
                label = labels[i]
            except (TypeError, KeyError):
                label = ' '
        else:
            label = '%d' % int(height)
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., height_factor*height,
                '{}'.format(label),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(ax.patches, labels=df.trips, height_factor=1.02)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The `hue` argument probably only makes sense to introduce a new dimension to the plot, not to show another quantity on the same dimension.

It's probably best to plot the bars without the `hue` argument (it's quite misleading to call it hue actually) and simply colorize the bars according to the values in the `"trips"` column.

This is shown also in this question: [Seaborn Barplot - Displaying Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214978/seaborn-barplot-displaying-values?rq=1).

The code here would look like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

di = np.arange(0,7)
avg  = np.array([708.852242,676.702190,684.572677,708.925340,781.767476,
                 1626.575057,1729.155673])
trips = np.array([114586,120936,118882,117868,108036,43740,37508])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[di, avg, trips], columns=["day_index","avg_duration", "trips"])

daysOfWeek = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', \
'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

plt.figure(figsize=(10,7));
sns.set_style('ticks')
v  = df.trips.values
colors=plt.cm.viridis((v-v.min())/(v.max()-v.min()))
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='day_index',   y='avg_duration', palette=colors)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    ax.text(row.day_index,row.avg_duration, row.trips, color='black', ha="center")

ax.set_xlabel("Week Days", fontsize=16, alpha=0.8)
ax.set_ylabel("Duration (seconds)", fontsize=16, alpha=0.8)
ax.set_title("Week's average Trip Duration", fontsize=18)
ax.set_xticklabels(daysOfWeek, fontsize=14)
ax.legend(fontsize=15)
sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Build the legend from a color map

- Remove `hue`. As already noted, the bars will not be centered when using this parameter, because they are placed according to the number of hue levels, and there are 7 levels in this case.
- Using the `palette` parameter instead of `hue`, places the bars directly over the ticks.
- This option requires "manually" associating `'trips'` with the colors and creating the legend.

  - [`patches`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch) uses `Patch` to create each item in the legend. (e.g. the rectangle, associated with color and name).

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

daysOfWeek = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

# specify the colors
colors = sns.color_palette('Reds_d', n_colors=len(df))

# create the plot
plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='day_index', y='avg_duration', palette=colors)

# plot cosmetics
ax.set_xlabel("Week Days", fontsize=18, alpha=0.8)
ax.set_ylabel("Average Duration (seconds)", fontsize=18, alpha=0.8)
ax.set_title("Week's average Trip Duration", fontsize=24)
ax.set_xticklabels(daysOfWeek, fontsize=16)
sns.despine()

# setup the legend

# map names to colors
cmap = dict(zip(df.trips, colors))

# create the rectangles for the legend
patches = [Patch(color=v, label=k) for k, v in cmap.items()]

# add the legend
ax.legend(title='Number of Trips', handles=patches, bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0.5), loc='center left', borderaxespad=0, fontsize=15)
```

[image]

---

- Alternatively, add bar labels with [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html), as shown with [How to add value labels on a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804). This option is available from `matplotlib v3.4.0`.

  - `labels=df.trips` can be used to pass custom labels directly from the dataframe column.

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='day_index', y='avg_duration', palette=colors)

# plot cosmetics
ax.set_xlabel("Week Days", fontsize=18, alpha=0.8)
ax.set_ylabel("Average Duration (seconds)", fontsize=18, alpha=0.8)
ax.set_title("Week's average Trip Duration", fontsize=24)
ax.set_xticklabels(daysOfWeek, fontsize=16)
sns.despine()

# add bar labels
_ = ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels=df.trips, padding=1)
```

[image]

```py
# add bar labels with customized text in a list comprehension
_ = ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels=[f'Trips: {v}' for v in df.trips], padding=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

```
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, \
                 x='day_index', \
                 y='avg_duration', \
                 hue='trips', \
                 dodge=False, \
                 palette=sns.color_palette("Reds_d", n_colors=7, desat=1))
```