# Seaborn plot bar time series x-axis : how to display the value of each bar

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

How to display value of each bar when your figure (bar) has time series as X-axis :

I have a dataframe df_final_seaborn :

[image]

```
    Covid-19 Madagascar Isan'ny olona
Daty        
2020-05-24  Sitrana isan'andro  4
2020-05-24  Maty                0
2020-05-25  Marary isan'andro   15
2020-05-25  Sitrana isan'andro  5
2020-05-25  Maty                0
```

and to plot bar with the following code :

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(30,15)},palette=['#F70A0A','#2A930C','#930C85'], font_scale=1.7)
# pour les axes 
ax = sns.barplot(x=df_final_seaborn.index,y='Isan\'ny olona',data=df_final_seaborn,hue='Covid-19 Madagascar')
sns.set_style("darkgrid" , {"ytick.major.size": 10 , "ytick.minor.size": 2 , 'grid.linestyle': '--'})
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('Daty', fontsize = 20)
plt.ylabel('Isan\'ny olona', fontsize = 20)
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='#999999', linestyle='-', alpha=0.2 , axis='y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FixedFormatter(df_sea.index.to_series().dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))
plt.show()
```

the result is :

[image]

My problem is how to display each value of bar :

I followed the same problem here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214978/seaborn-barplot-displaying-values) by addind the code below

```
for index , row in df_final_seaborn.iterrows():
   ax.text(row.name,row['Isan\'ny olona'], round(row['Isan\'ny olona'],0), color='black', ha="center")


plt.show()

Out : TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'
```

for information when I put

```
for index , row in df_final_seaborn.iterrows():
    print(index)
    print(row)
```

the result will be :

[image]

Another solution  is via  matplotlib like here : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228069/how-to-display-the-value-of-the-bar-on-each-bar-with-pyplot-barh)

adding this before : plt.show()

```
for i , v in enumerate (df_final_seaborn):
       plt.text(df_final_seaborn.iloc[i], v + 0.01, str(v))
```

out :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-127-717d236faadf> in <module>
     12 ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FixedFormatter(df_sea.index.to_series().dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))
     13 for i , v in enumerate (df_final_seaborn):
---> 14        plt.text(df_final_seaborn.iloc[i], v + 0.01, str(v))
     15 #      print(i)
     16 #      print(v)

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't iterate over the dataframe, since the correspondence between rows and bars are not guaranteed. Instead, iterate over bars:

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(30,15)},palette=['#F70A0A','#2A930C','#930C85'], font_scale=1.7)
# pour les axes 
ax = sns.barplot(x=df_final_seaborn.index,y='Isan\'ny olona',data=df_final_seaborn,hue='Covid-19 Madagascar')
sns.set_style("darkgrid" , {"ytick.major.size": 10 , "ytick.minor.size": 2 , 'grid.linestyle': '--'})
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

for patch in ax.patches:
    x, width, height = patch.get_x(), patch.get_width(), patch.get_height()
    color = patch.get_facecolor()

    # ignore 0 and nan values
    if height is None or height==0: continue

    ax.text( x+width/2, height+0.1, f'{height}',ha='center',color=color)
```

Output:

[image]