# Add values above bars on a bar chart in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph, visualization

I have the following code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure()

languages =['Python', 'SQL', 'Java', 'C++', 'JavaScript']
pos = np.arange(len(languages))
popularity = [56, 39, 34, 34, 29]

bars = plt.bar(pos, popularity, align='center', linewidth=0, color='lightslategrey')
bars[0].set_color('#1F77B4')

plt.xticks(pos, languages, alpha=0.8)

plt.ylabel("")
plt.title('Top 5 Languages for Math & Data \nby % popularity on Stack Overflow', alpha=0.8)

plt.tick_params(top='off', bottom='off', left='off', right='off', labelleft='off', labelbottom='on')

for spine in plt.gca().spines.values():
    spine.set_visible(False)

for index, value in enumerate(str(popularity)): 
    plt.text(index,value,str(popularity))

plt.show()
```

I am trying to label the values from the Y-axis above each bar (the Y-values).

However, this code is not doing that.

Could anybody point out to me where I am going wrong?

Comment: See the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62024019/seaborn-plot-bar-time-series-x-axis-how-to-display-the-value-of-each-bar/62024286#62024286).

Comment: @QuangHoang I was almost there, please see below for solution.

Comment: add `ha='center'` to center your values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there; You only need to change the last for loop to be like so:

```
...
...
for index, value in enumerate(popularity):
    plt.text(index,value, str(value))
plt.show()
```

which will generate this plot:
[image]