# How to get the label values on a bar chat with seaborn on a categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

Shown below is the syntax used to get the bar char for a categorical data on seaborn

```
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


IN: data['coast'].dtypes
OUT: 
CategoricalDtype(categories=[0, 1], ordered=False)


IN: data['coast'].value_counts()  
OUT: 
0    21450
1      163
Name: coast, dtype: int64


IN: sn.factorplot('coast', data=data, kind='count')
OUT:
```

[image]

1. How can I get the value count on the bar chart shown below.
   [image]
2. How to get the percentage value on the bar chart shown below.
   [image]

Comment: What version of matplotlib do you have?

Comment: @BigBen version 3.4.1

Comment: I'd look at https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label

Comment: @BigBen it didn't help my need :(  hope you will be a give me a solution  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
# imports
import sys # for retreiving package version matplotlib
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# package versions
print('numpy      :', np.__version__)
print('pandas     :', pd.__version__)
print('matplotlib :', sys.modules['matplotlib'].__version__)
print('seaborn    :', np.__version__)

# set seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(100)

# generate data
n = 15
data = pd.DataFrame({'coast': np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=n, dtype=int)})
data['coast'] = data['coast'].astype('category')

# plot data
ax = sns.countplot(x='coast', data=data)
plt.bar_label(ax.containers[0]) # plot bar labels
plt.show()
```

Results:

```
numpy      : 1.21.0
pandas     : 1.3.0
matplotlib : 3.4.2
seaborn    : 1.21.0
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

#### Percentage counts

- Use [`sns.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) with a [custom percentage estimator](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1027)
- Label the percentages using the new built-in [`ax.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html) and its `fmt` param

```py
ax = sns.barplot(x='coast', y='coast', estimator=lambda x: len(x) / len(data) * 100, data=data)
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt='%.f%%')
ax.set_ylabel('%')
```

[image]

---

#### Regular counts

Save the axes handle from [`sns.countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) and use the new [`ax.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html):

```py
ax = sns.countplot(x='coast', data=data)
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])
```

Or for the facet-based [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) (formerly `sns.factorplot`), extract the axes from the facet grid before using [`ax.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html):

```py
grid = sns.catplot(x='coast', kind='count', data=data)
ax = grid.axes[0, 0]
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])
```

[image]