# seaborn histplot - print y-values above each bar

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

How to print y-values above each bar, please? Thank you

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = [6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 9, 4, 1, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 1, 7, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 1, 7, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 1, 6, 1, 9, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 2, 1, 9, 4, 1, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8, 2, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 9, 4, 1, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax = sns.histplot(data, discrete=True, kde=False, stat='percent') 

plt.show()
```

Comment: Is there any more sophisticated, automated approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have matplotlib 3.4.0 or higher, you can use `bar_label`. More info [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html)

Code would be something like this...

```
ax = sns.histplot(data, discrete=True, kde=False, stat='percent') 
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])
```

Comment: Thank you and how to add a format. I tried: `ax.bar_label('{:.2f} %'.format(ax.containers[0]))`

Comment: `ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt='%.2f%%')`

Comment: Thanks @JohnC. Some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68320207/how-to-get-the-label-values-on-a-bar-chat-with-seaborn-on-a-categorical-data/68322925#68322925)