# seaborn display values on barplot

Tags: seaborn

my code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plot_df = pd.DataFrame({"total":[30], "matches":[16],"mismatches":[7]})
p = sns.catplot(data=plot_df, kind="bar")
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    p.text(row.name,row.total.row.matches,row.mismatches, color='black', ha="center")
plt.show()
```

I trying follow this solution:
[Seaborn Barplot - Displaying Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214978/seaborn-barplot-displaying-values)

But in my case I get a error:

> AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'text'

What's wrong?

Comment: `catplot` is a figure-level interface returning a `FacetGrid`, different from `barplot`, which returns a matplotlib `Axes`.

Comment: Also you'll want to use [`bar_label`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68323374/9245853) if you've got the latest version of matplotlib.

Comment: I got this: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'bar_label'

Comment: As I said, `catplot` returns a `FacetGrid`, which does not have a `bar_label` attribute. You need to work with a matplotlib `Axes`, not a `FacetGrid`.

Comment: For example `p.axes[0,0].bar_label(p.axes[0,0].containers[0])`.

Comment: Adapting JohanC code, this worked here for a single plot with more than 1 container: `[p.axes[0,0].bar_label(container) for container in p.axes[0,0].containers]`