# How to add vertically centered labels in bar chart matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a problem which I simplified as below, **I would love if anyone suggest me the code in seaborn like what I want to achieve.**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


a = [2000, 4000, 3000, 8000, 6000, 3000, 3000, 4000, 2000, 4000, 3000, 8000, 6000, 3000, 3000, 4000, 2000, 4000, 3000, 8000, 6000, 3000, 3000, 4000]
b = [0.8, 0.9, 0.83, 0.81, 0.86, 0.89, 0.89, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.83, 0.81, 0.86, 0.89, 0.89, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.83, 0.81, 0.86, 0.89, 0.89, 0.8]
c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
ax12 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.bar(c, a)
ax12.plot(c, b, 'o-', color="red", markersize=12,
          markerfacecolor='Yellow', markeredgewidth=2, linewidth=2)
ax12.set_ylim(bottom=0, top=1, emit=True, auto=False)

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I am trying to achieve the labels in the center and vertical as shown in the following figure.

[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of matplotlib 3.4.0, use [`Axes.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html):

- `label_type='center'` places the labels at the center of the bars
- `rotation=90` rotates them 90 deg

Since this is a regular bar chart, we only need to label one bar container `ax1.containers[0]`:

```
ax1.bar_label(ax1.containers[0], label_type='center', rotation=90, color='white')
```

But if this were a grouped/stacked bar chart, we should iterate all `ax1.containers`:

```
for container in ax1.containers:
    ax1.bar_label(container, label_type='center', rotation=90, color='white')
```

[image]

---

### seaborn version

I just noticed the question text asks about seaborn, in which case we can use [`sns.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) and [`sns.pointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html). We can still [use `bar_label` with seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68323374/13138364) via the underlying axes.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# put the lists into a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c})

# create the barplot and vertically centered labels
ax1 = sns.barplot(data=df, x='c', y='a', color='green')
ax1.bar_label(ax1.containers[0], label_type='center', rotation=90, color='white')

ax12 = ax1.twinx()
ax12.set_ylim(bottom=0, top=1, emit=True, auto=False)

# create the pointplot with x=[0, 1, 2, ...]
# this is because that's where the bars are located (due to being categorical)
sns.pointplot(ax=ax12, data=df.reset_index(), x='index', y='b', color='red')
```

[image]