# write custom values above bar plot made by seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, label, seaborn, bar-chart

I want to write custom values above my bars in barplot which I made using sns.barplot. My custom values are available in the same DataFrame under another column. This question has been answered [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214978/how-to-display-custom-values-on-a-bar-plot) however,  they do not consider Hue. How would you write custom values sourced in the same DataFrame when Hue is defined?

DataFrame:

| XData | YData | Type | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 123 | TypeA | 001 |
| Y | 234 | TypeA | 010 |
| X | 345 | TypeB | 100 |
| Y | 567 | TypeB | 000 |

here is my plot:

```
MyBarPlot = sns.barplot(data=DataFrame, x="XData", y="YData",hue="Type",width=0.8, errorbar=('ci', 95))


DataFrameGrouped = DataFrame.groupby(['XData','YData']).label.mean()


for container in MyBarPlot .containers:
 MyBarPlot.bar_label(container[0], labels=DataFrameGrouped, padding=3, fmt='%.1f')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the DataFrame and seaborn plot you shared, the error might be stemming from the attempt to use 'label' from the DataFrameGrouped directly, which is not defined as a 'label' attribute for the grouped object. The arrangement is the problem here as it can be a big issue when using hue.

```py
MyBarPlot = sns.barplot(data=df, x="XData", y="YData", hue="Type", width=0.8)
plt.ylim(0, df['YData'].max() + 100)  # This is to make sure there is enough space for labels above the bars

# Create a nested dictionary from the DataFrame for easy label access
label_dict = df.set_index(['XData', 'Type'])['Label'].to_dict()

for i, bar in enumerate(MyBarPlot.patches):
    # Calculate the label position
    height = bar.get_height()
    x = bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2
    y = height

    # Get the corresponding label for this bar from label_dict
    label = label_dict[(df['XData'].unique()[i // 2], df['Type'].unique()[i % 2])]

    # Add the label to the bar
    plt.text(x, y, label, ha='center', va='bottom')

plt.show()
```

I have attached a collab sheet with the results.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ipt3FS5WkDjDc0uVm9RSgtgeI4uSFlUC?usp=sharing