# numpy's argsort on rows work not as expected

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a simple python code segment that intended to sort each row of a 2D numpy matrix

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X=np.random.random((3,3))
>>> X
array([[ 0.57758986,  0.76771506,  0.94539164],
       [ 0.37619117,  0.85602478,  0.21527702],
       [ 0.41134957,  0.47028597,  0.0672778 ]])
>>> X.argsort(axis=-1)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

What I am trying to do is sorting on each row so that I can get the order of each row from min to max, so I am expecting the output of X.argsort to be:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

However definitely argsort does not work in this way, do I have any mis-understanding of the argsort of numpy?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Why do you expect `[1, 2, 0]` for the second two rows?

Comment: It looks like you want to *rank* the rows, not `argsort` them.  They are not the same thing.

Comment: See, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284646/rank-items-in-an-array-using-python-numpy

Comment: second row: 0.37x, 0.85x, 0.21x, should their order, from minimum to maximum, 1, 2, 0?

Comment: If `X = [0.37, 0.85, 0.21]`, `argsort(X)` gives [2, 0, 1], because the sorted array is `[X[2], X[0], X[1]]`.

Comment: ok, now I understand, it is really my mis-understanding