# Get rankings from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array like the following

```
values = [0.1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.65, 0.2, 0.7]
```

I need to know both the value and the index of the top value and I get that with

```
int(np.argmax(values))
max(values)
```

But now I also need to know the second-highest and third-highest values from the array and preserve the index accordingly. How can I modify my code to get those values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get indices of N maximum values in a NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-do-i-get-indices-of-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array)

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284646/rank-items-in-an-array-using-python-numpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `np.argsort`, it gives you the indices of the largest numbers.

```
indices = np.argsort(values)[::-1]
print(indices)
```

The `[::-1]` reverses the list, which is necessary because `argsort` returns the indices in increasing order. This gives:

```
[1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 0]
```

Then you can use

```
values[indices[n]]
```

to retrieve the `n`-th largest value.

Answer (score 2):

just remove the highest value and then use `int(np.argmax(values))`

Answer (score 1):

```
np.argsort(values)
```

Returns

```
array([0, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 - using python lists:

```
values = [0.1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.65, 0.2, 0.7]
#Create a copy of the list
vals = values[:]
print(vals)
for i in range(len(vals)):
    m = max(vals)
    print(i+1,'-',values.index(m),'-',m)
    vals.remove(m)
```

Method 2 - using numpy as explained by piripiri:

```
import numpy as np
indices = np.argsort(values)[::-1]
print(indices)

for i in range(len(values)):
    print(i+1,'-',indices[i],'-',values[indices[i]])
```