# Rolling percent rank in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Following is my dataframe. I am trying to calculate rolling 5 period percent rank of `ATR`. `RollingPercentRank` is my desired output.

```
       symbol         Day      time       ATR  RollingPercentRank
316356    SPY  11/29/2018  10:35:00  0.377880                 NaN
316357    SPY  11/29/2018  10:40:00  0.391092                 NaN
316358    SPY  11/29/2018  10:45:00  0.392983                 NaN
316359    SPY  11/29/2018  10:50:00  0.399685                 NaN
316360    SPY  11/29/2018  10:55:00  0.392716                 0.2
316361    SPY  11/29/2018  11:00:00  0.381445                 0.2
316362   AAPL  11/29/2018  11:05:00  0.387300                 NaN
316363   AAPL  11/29/2018  11:10:00  0.390570                 NaN
316364   AAPL  11/29/2018  11:15:00  0.381313                 NaN
316365   AAPL  11/29/2018  11:20:00  0.398182                 NaN
316366   AAPL  11/29/2018  11:25:00  0.377364                 0.6
316367   AAPL  11/29/2018  11:30:00  0.373627                 0.2
```

As of the 5th row, I want to apply the percent rank function to all 5 previous values(1st row to 5th row) of `ATR` within a group. And as of the 6th row, I want to again apply the rank function to all 5 previous values(2nd row to 6th row)  of `ATR`.
I have tried the following which gives a "'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rank' " error.

```
df['RollingPercentRank'] = df.groupby(['symbol'])['ATR'].rolling(window=5,min_periods=5,center=False).apply(lambda x: x.rank(pct=True)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC as I don't get the expected output you showed, but to use `rank`, you need a `pd.Series` and then you only want the last value of this percentage Series of 5 elements so it would be:

```
print (df.groupby(['symbol'])['ATR']
         .rolling(window=5,min_periods=5,center=False)
         .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).rank(pct=True).iloc[-1]))

symbol  i     
AAPL    316362    NaN
        316363    NaN
        316364    NaN
        316365    NaN
        316366    0.2
        316367    0.2
SPY     316356    NaN
        316357    NaN
        316358    NaN
        316359    NaN
        316360    0.6
        316361    0.2
```

Because `x` ix a `numpy` array, it is possible to get the same result using [twice `argsort`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6266510/9274732) and to create the column, a `reset_index` at the end:

```
win_val = 5
df['RollingPercentRank'] = (df.groupby(['symbol'])['ATR']
                              .rolling(window=win_val,min_periods=5,center=False)
                              .apply(lambda x: x.argsort().argsort()[-1]+1)
                              .reset_index(level=0,drop=True)/win_val)

print (df)
       symbol         Day      time       ATR  RollingPercentRank

316356    SPY  11/29/2018  10:35:00  0.377880                 NaN
316357    SPY  11/29/2018  10:40:00  0.391092                 NaN
316358    SPY  11/29/2018  10:45:00  0.392983                 NaN
316359    SPY  11/29/2018  10:50:00  0.399685                 NaN
316360    SPY  11/29/2018  10:55:00  0.392716                 0.6
316361    SPY  11/29/2018  11:00:00  0.381445                 0.2
316362   AAPL  11/29/2018  11:05:00  0.387300                 NaN
316363   AAPL  11/29/2018  11:10:00  0.390570                 NaN
316364   AAPL  11/29/2018  11:15:00  0.381313                 NaN
316365   AAPL  11/29/2018  11:20:00  0.398182                 NaN
316366   AAPL  11/29/2018  11:25:00  0.377364                 0.2
316367   AAPL  11/29/2018  11:30:00  0.373627                 0.2
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Will including a `reset_index` at the end of your first solution work? I got all NaN with that approach. Your second solution with `argsort`  works great.

Comment: @gibbz00 it should work if you specify to reset only `level=0` and `drop=True`. For performance, I recommand to use the second solution. I think creating a `pd.Series` is not always efficient, but I did not time these two solutions