# changing values of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a given numpy array, data.
I want to change its values in the ascending order from 0.
I could solve it by manually making the look up table, LUT.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[2, 6, 16, 39, 43],
                        [43, 6, 16, 39, 2]])


LUT={2:0,
    6:1,
    16:2,
    39:3,
    43:4} 

def changer(X):   
    res = np.copy(X)    
    for i, j in LUT.items():
        res[X==i] = j
    return res       

result = changer(data)
print (result)

[[0 1 2 3 4]
 [4 1 2 3 0]]
```

The result is correct as I expected.
However, sometimes, I am lazy to make LUT manually.
So, how could I get the same results programmatically?

## edit

I tried to make dictionary, LUT as follows.

```
list = [2,6,16,39,43]

LUT = {}
for i in enumerate(list):
    LUT.update({list[i]: i})

But, 

D.update({list[i]: i})
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to hard code any look up tables in high level code into python! Except with some edge case scenarios this will hurt you. Please explain what you are trying to do and why are you trying to do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rank items in an array using Python/NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284646/rank-items-in-an-array-using-python-numpy)

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?`dict(enumerate([2, 6, 16, 39, 43]))`

Comment: @mad_ yes. Could you see my edit?

Comment: @mad_ how can i inverse, dict(enumerate([2, 6, 16, 39, 43]))?

Comment: By converting values to keys `dict(zip(d.values(),d.keys()))`

Comment: thanks @mad_ it solved my problem           .

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.unique` with the `return_inverse` flag:

```
data = np.array([[2, 6, 16, 39, 43],
                 [43, 6, 16, 39, 2]])

unq, ranked = np.unique(data, return_inverse=True)
```

`unique` without `axis` set flattens, so we need to reshape

```
ranked = ranked.reshape(data.shape)
ranked
# array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
#        [4, 1, 2, 3, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, np_lu should be automatically generated from your data.

```
In [24]: np_lu=sorted(set(data.ravel()))
In [25]: np_lu
Out[25]: [2, 6, 16, 39, 43]
```

Create an array of indices 2->0, 6->1, ... 43->4

```
In [29]: indx=np.array(np_lu)
In [33]: d=np.zeros(indx.max()+1)
In [34]: d[indx]=np.arange(len(indx))
In [35]: d
Out[35]:
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  4.])

In [36]: data
Out[36]:
array([[ 2,  6, 16, 39, 43],
       [43,  6, 16, 39,  2]])
```

Create a result array, res.

```
In [37]: res=np.zeros_like(data)
```

Fill res with the data in d, indexed by data.

```
In [41]: res=d[data]
In [42]: res
Out[42]:
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  0.]])
```

This will only work for data of int type.  There's probably a lot of tidying up that can be done in my code.

Answer (score 0):

#### I think this is really [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

> Returns the indices that would sort an array.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[2, 6, 16, 39, 43],
                        [43, 6, 16, 39, 2]])
data.argsort(1).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 1, 2, 3, 0]]
```

#### And to go backwards giving 1D array, l, and 2D array of indexes, iarr:

```
l = np.array([2, 6, 16, 39, 43])
iarr = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 1, 2, 3, 0]])
```

We can use broadcasting:

```
l[iarr]
```

Output:

```
array([[ 2,  6, 16, 39, 43],
       [43,  6, 16, 39,  2]])
```

Comment: Is there also a way to reverse the output to input?

Comment: Reverse the output?  Change the sort order?  [[4->0],[0->4]] like this?

Comment: to get `input` from `output`.

Comment: `[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 1, 2, 3, 0]]` into `[[2, 6, 16, 39, 43],
                        [43, 6, 16, 39, 2]]`

Comment: Given a list of [2,6,16,39,43] and [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 1, 2, 3, 0]] -> [[2, 6, 16, 39, 43], [43, 6, 16, 39, 2]]?

Comment: but we do not know `l`, we know only `data` and `iarr`

Comment: Yes, then it is not possible.  You can't got from a an index to numbers with a reference.

Answer (score -1):

if i get right your needs , all you need is:

```
import numpy as np
lst = np.array([[i for i in range(len(data[0]))],[i for i in range(len(data[1])-1,-1,-1)]])
```

Comment: Nope. Not even close. OP is looking for functionality similar to lookup. Your code just iterates and print index of items in some fashion.

Comment: he wanted to use lookup as a method to resolve his problems,
looking over his desired outcome , i think this nails it...

Comment: Can you confirm if the output matches? This does not give the desired results. Thanks

Comment: @mad_ i ran it on his initial data set (array with 2 lists)with my commands and it worked