# Trying to rank two arrays at the same time

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get a rank of worst case scenarios but there are two different types of worst case scenarios that I am trying to compare. So I have two separate arrays and I am trying to compare them to one another.

I used the sorting method from the link below and it works when sorting with one array but not with two.

[Rank items in an array using Python/NumPy, without sorting array twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284646/rank-items-in-an-array-using-python-numpy-without-sorting-array-twice)

```
CI_SUM_1 = numpy.array([2,1,7,23])
CI_SUM_2 = numpy.array([4,0,22,3])
order = CI_SUM_1.argsort() + CI_SUM_2.argsort() 
rank = order.argsort()
print(rank)
```

In the above example it is adding the ranks together(which makes sense), so I am getting `[0,2,1,3]`. Which isn't what I am looking for. I am trying to get 8 ranks so I can see individual ranks.

Expected result should be something like `[2,1,5,7,4,0,6,3]` which is the ranks when putting the two arrays side by side. Basically what I want is an absolute rank not a rank per array. So I only want one 1 unless the two values are the same. I don't want two arrays from 0-3, I want one from 0-7.

Comment: Alright, I just added the expected output. Not sure if it makes the most sense but basically what I want is an absolute rank not a rank per array. So I only want one 1 unless the two values are the same. I don't want two arrays from 0-3, I want one from 0-7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [`concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) the two arrays `CI_SUM_1` and `CI_SUM_2` before using `argsort` such as:

```
print (np.concatenate([CI_SUM_1,CI_SUM_2]).argsort().argsort())
array([2, 1, 5, 7, 4, 0, 6, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I actually just did that but with a different order and am getting a slightly different answer. What I did was make a variable 'z' which did the concatenate the did two argsorts with different lines and had it print which gave me [5,1,0,7,4,2,6,3]. So the 2,5 and 0 are different. Any idea why?
    `z = np.concatenate((CI_SUM_1,CI_SUM_2))
     order1 = z.argsort

Comment: Never mind, I was printing order rather than rank. Thank you for the help! I upvoted but don't have the reputation for it to show haha.

Comment: @greenbur I see, you were pretty close with what you tried :) thanks for the ghost upvote haha