# Change barpolot color in based on a range of x values

Tags: python, colors, seaborn, bar-chart

I am trying to make a seaborn barplot that plots values (baseball team ERA's) from different years - and then highlight the bars based on the year ranges under different management.

```py
import pandas as pd
import pybaseball as pyb
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np

cards_pitching_df = pyb.team_pitching(start_season=1996,end_season=2020)
cards_pitching_df = cards_pitching_df.loc[(cards_pitching_df['Team'] == "STL"), :"Pitches"]
cards_pitching_df = cards_pitching_df.sort_values(by='Season', ascending=False)

era = list(cards_pitching_df['ERA'])
season = list(cards_pitching_df['Season'])

df_season_era = list(zip(era,season))
df_season_era = pd.DataFrame(df_season_era, columns=['ERA','Season'])
df_season_era
```

```
        ERA    Season
    0   3.92    2020
    1   3.82    2019
    2   3.85    2018
    3   4.01    2017
    4   4.08    2016
    5   2.94    2015
    6   3.50    2014
    7   3.43    2013
    8   3.71    2012
    9   3.79    2011
```

And as of now, I have my seaborn barplot highlighting based on the ERA values, see below. But what I want is one color (say blue) for the ERA's between the years 1996-2011, green for 2012-2017, and orange for 2018-2020, which are the x - values.

```
era_chart_2 = sns.barplot(x=season, y=era, data=df_season_era)
for bar in era_chart2.patches:
    if bar.get_height() > 3.5:
        bar.set_color('grey')    
    else:
        bar.set_color('green')
```

[image: See the chart it is now producing here]

Any suggestions on how to make the bars colored in this way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `palette` to add the range of preferred colors in seaborn.

Use this:

```py
palette=['blue' if val in range(1996,2012) else 'green' if val in range(2012,2018) else 'orange' for val in sorted(df_season_era['Season'].tolist())]

sns.barplot('Season', 'ERA', data=df_season_era, palette=palette)
```

Notice: In `range()` function the upper limit is always `upper_limit - 1`. So that is why I have used `range(1996,2012)` and `range(2012,2018)` instead of `range(1996,2011)` and `range(2012,2017)`

Comment: This is almost working! For some reason, the colors aren't plotting out right. it shows 1996-1998 as orange, 1999-2004 as green and the rest as blue... see here:

```
palette = ['blue' if value in range(1996,2012) else 'green' if value in range(2012,2018) else 'orange' for value in df_season_era['Season']]

sns.barplot('Season', 'ERA', data=df_season_era, palette=palette)

```

Comment: Can you update the question by adding code of your full dataframe? Let me check it

Comment: You should also print the `palette` variable and see whether it's color values matches with `season` column values

Comment: Yes, it prints the values incorrectly.

['orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue']

It should be the exact opposite

Comment: @cam417 can you add the code of creating your full dataframe?

Comment: how does that look?

Comment: You have only shown what your dataframe looks like but you have not shown the code for creating your dataframe, please provide the code for creating your dataframe so that I can also create the same dataframe and check what is wrong

Comment: Sorry about that, I added all of it above

Comment: @cam417 ok I found the mistake. `df_season_era['Season']` was printing from descending order (2020 to 1996) which was the main reason for color mixmax. I sorted that list in ascending order. Now the code works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
data = titanic.groupby("deck").size()   # data underlying bar plot in question

pal = sns.color_palette("Greens_d", len(data))
rank = data.argsort().argsort()   # http://stackoverflow.com/a/6266510/1628638
sns.barplot(x=data.index, y=data, palette=np.array(pal[::-1])[rank])

plt.show()
```

This should work!

Comment: Thanks for the response. So is this coloring by range or by value?? I want mine to essentially ignore the value and color by the range of x values. So all the years between 1996 and 2011 be the same color (regardless of their value) and so on

Answer (score 0):

I have a variation on Sahaj approach which takes into account the proportions of the bars instead of just the rank, i just wanted to post it here for future reference and in the hope someone finds it usefull

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def color_bar_by_y(barplot, palette):
    patches = barplot.ax.patches
    patches_list = [x for x in patches]
    patches_list.sort(key=lambda x:x.get_height())
    min, max = patches_list[0].get_height(), patches_list[-1].get_height()
    scale = np.linspace(start=min, stop=max, num=len(patches_list)*10)
    palette = sns.color_palette(palette, len(scale))
    for p in patches_list:
        height = p.get_height()
        idx = np.argmin(np.absolute(scale-height))
        p.set_facecolor(palette[idx])

sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

g = sns.catplot(
    data=titanic,
    x="deck", 
    kind='count'
)

color_bar_by_y(g, 'Greens_d')

plt.show()
```

explanation: in the function i access the shapes on the axes directly. I add them to a list which i sort by height.

next I create a linear list of values from the min and max values from these heights. To get a nice spacing of colors I multiply the number of bars by 10.
after that i create a color palette with the same length as this scale

to assign the right color to the shapes i loop through the bars and get the idx of the nearest value from the linear list. (reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-nearest-value-and-the-index-of-numpy-array/)