# Does numpy have a function similar to pandas rank?

Tags: python, numpy, ranking, rank, percentile

I have an array of 500 numbers and I'd like to calculate the percentile of each value:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = np.random.random(500)

desired_output = pd.DataFrame(df).rank(pct=True)
```

Except without using pandas, since I have this in a long loop and it must be as fast as possible.

Comment: SciPy has [`rankdata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html); see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284646/rank-items-in-an-array-using-python-numpy-without-sorting-array-twice for more options.

Comment: *"I'd like to calculate the percentile of each value"* Did you see [`numpy.percentile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html)?

Comment: You can "rank" data (0 ... n-1)  using numpy by `argsort`ing twice: `ranks = df.argsort().argsort()`. You can get the percentile via `desired_output = (ranks + 1) / df.shape[-1]`; note however that it does not deal with ties like pandas, so if that is necessary you will need to do more processing.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser didn't think it needed to be said "without iterating through row by row which would be extremely slow".