# rank and order in R

Tags: r, sorting, r-faq

i am having trouble understanding the difference between the R function `rank` and the R function `order`.  they seem to produce the same output:

```
> rank(c(10,30,20,50,40))
[1] 1 3 2 5 4
> order(c(10,30,20,50,40))
[1] 1 3 2 5 4
```

Could somebody shed some light on this for me?
Thanks

Comment: A blog post about this is: http://www.portfolioprobe.com/2012/07/26/r-inferno-ism-order-is-not-rank/

Comment: I also wrote a [blog post](https://ro-che.info/articles/2016-03-19-rank-vs-order-r) about this. In particular, I try to explain why the OP is seeing identical results from `rank` and `order`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the order() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315601/understanding-the-order-function)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```r
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(1:50, 30)    
x
# [1] 14 19 28 43 10 41 42 29 27  3  9  7 44 15 48 18 25 33 13 34 47 39 49  4 30 46  1 40 20  8
rank(x)
# [1]  9 12 16 25  7 23 24 17 15  2  6  4 26 10 29 11 14 19  8 20 28 21 30  3 18 27  1 22 13  5
order(x)
# [1] 27 10 24 12 30 11  5 19  1 14 16  2 29 17  9  3  8 25 18 20 22 28  6  7  4 13 26 21 15 23
```

`rank` returns a vector with the "rank" of each value.  the number in the first position is the 9th lowest. `order` returns the indices that would put the initial vector `x` in order.

The 27th value of `x` is the lowest, so `27` is the first element of `order(x)` - and if you look at `rank(x)`, the 27th element is `1`.

```r
x[order(x)]
# [1]  1  3  4  7  8  9 10 13 14 15 18 19 20 25 27 28 29 30 33 34 39 40 41 42 43 44 46 47 48 49
```

Comment: Also notice the difference when there are ties.

Answer (score 13):

As it turned out this was a special case and made things confusing.  I explain below for anyone interested:

`rank` returns the order of each element in an ascending list

`order` returns the index each element would have in an ascending list

Comment: This is very easy to understand thank you. Every other explanation was just more confusion

Answer (score 8):

I always find it confusing to think about the difference between the two, and I always think, "how can I get to `order` using `rank`"?

Starting with Justin's example:

#### Order using rank:

```
## Setup example to match Justin's example
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(1:50, 30) 

## Make a vector to store the sorted x values
xx = integer(length(x))

## i is the index, ir is the ith "rank" value
i = 0
for(ir in rank(x)){
    i = i + 1
    xx[ir] = x[i]
}

all(xx==x[order(x)])
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 6):

`rank` is more complicated and not neccessarily an index (integer):

```
> rank(c(1))
[1] 1
> rank(c(1,1))
[1] 1.5 1.5
> rank(c(1,1,1))
[1] 2 2 2
> rank(c(1,1,1,1))
[1] 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
```

Answer (score 6):

In layman's language, `order` gives the actual place/position of a value after sorting the values
For eg:

```
a<-c(3,4,2,7,8,5,1,6)
sort(a) [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

The position of `1` in `a` is 7. similarly position of `2` in `a` is 3.

```
order(a) [1] 7 3 1 2 6 8 4 5
```

Comment: But the question was about the difference between `rank` and `order`.

Answer (score 1):

as is stated by ?order() in R prompt, 
order just return a permutation which sort the original vector into ascending/descending order.
suppose that we have a vector

```
A<-c(1,4,3,6,7,4);
A.sort<-sort(A);
```

then

```
order(A) == match(A.sort,A);
rank(A) == match(A,A.sort);
```

besides, i find that order has the following property(not validated theoratically):

```
1 order(A)∈(1,length(A))
2 order(order(order(....order(A)....))):if you take the order of A in odds number of times, the results remains the same, so as to even number of times.
```

Answer (score 0):

some observations:

```
set.seed(0)
x<-matrix(rnorm(10),1)
dm<-diag(length(x))

# compute  rank from order and backwards:
rank(x)  == col(x)%*%dm[order(x),]
order(x) == col(x)%*%dm[rank(x),]


# in special cases like this
x<-cumsum(rep(c(2,0),times=5))+rep(c(0,-1),times=5)
# they are equal
order(x)==rank(x)
```

Comment: ``diag(length(x))[order(x),]==t(diag(length(x))[rank(x),])`` is the relationship between rank and order

Comment: rank() is the inverse permutation to order(). some permutations are their own inverse and it is in these cases that ``order(x)==rank(x)``. In general, ``all(x==x[order(x)][rank(x)])`` always holds.