# How to change the order of display of list.files(): for example based on part of the whole name of files

Tags: r

I have several nc files in a directory. The naming of the files is complex,for instance :

```
 LPRM-AMSR_E_L3_D_SOILM3_V002-20120601T214436Z_20100801.nc
```

I want to list the files so that I can work with them,it seemed that R listed them ina certain order.

How can I tell R change the default display of list.files , and **order** them  the files based on _yearmonthday only  which represents yearmonthday in all files

LPRM-AMSR_E_L3_D_SOILM3_V002-20120601T214436Z **_20100801**

to list files in R I use this :

```
a<-list.files("D:\\semon", "*.nc", full.names = TRUE)
```

I get this :

```
[1] "D:\\LPRM-AMSR_E_L3_D_SOILM3_V002-20120603T170757Z_20110916.nc"
[2] "D:\\/LPRM-AMSR_E_L3_D_SOILM3_V002-20120603T194524Z_20110917.nc"
[3] "D:\\/LPRM-AMSR_E_L3_D_SOILM3_V002-20120604T122649Z_20110915.nc"
```

I want to get this :

```
[1] "D:\\/LPRM-AMSR_E_L3_D_SOILM3_V002-20120604T122649Z_20110915.nc"
[2] "D:\\/LPRM-AMSR_E_L3_D_SOILM3_V002-20120603T170757Z_20110916.nc"
[3] "D:\\/LPRM-AMSR_E_L3_D_SOILM3_V002-20120603T194524Z_20110917.nc"
```

Comment: Your question is about the order??

Comment: (-1), see comment under my answer

Comment: @Barry I edit your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    a<-list.files("D:\\semon", "*_20100801.nc", full.names = TRUE)
```

You want this :

```
 a<-list.files("D:\\semon", "*_[0-9]{8}[.]nc", full.names = TRUE)
```

or to be match a classic date pattern:

```
  a<-list.files("D:\\semon", "*_\\d{4}\\d{2}\\d{2}[.]nc", full.names = TRUE)
```

**EDIT**

The OP is looking to order the output of `list.files`

```
   a<-list.files("D:\\semon", "*.nc", full.names = TRUE)
   a[order(gsub('.*_(\\d{8})[.].*','\\1',a))]
```

For example:

```
a <- c('D:\\AMSER\\amser2010+2011/LPRM-AMSR_E_L3_D_SOILM3_V002-20120603T170757Z_20110916.nc',
        "D:\\AMSER\\amser2010+2011/LPRM-AMSR_E_L3_D_SOILM3_V002-20120603T194524Z_20110917.nc",
        "D:\\AMSER\\amser2010+2011/LPRM-AMSR_E_L3_D_SOILM3_V002-20120604T122649Z_20110915.nc")

a[order(gsub('.*_(\\d{8})[.].*','\\1',a))]

[1] "D:\\AMSER\\amser2010+2011/LPRM-AMSR_E_L3_D_SOILM3_V002-20120604T122649Z_20110915.nc"
[2] "D:\\AMSER\\amser2010+2011/LPRM-AMSR_E_L3_D_SOILM3_V002-20120603T170757Z_20110916.nc"
[3] "D:\\AMSER\\amser2010+2011/LPRM-AMSR_E_L3_D_SOILM3_V002-20120603T194524Z_20110917.nc"
```

Comment: +1 for solving the OP's question after quite some iterations of "question refinement" :)

Comment: @Barry and rank is different from order(at least in R) . see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289224/rank-and-order-in-r).

Answer (score 2):

To list all files whose filenames end on eight numbers plus ".nc":

```
a <- list.files("/path/to/your/files", "_[0-9]{8}\\.nc$", full.names = TRUE)
```

To get only valid dates, you would have to adapt the pattern a little, but it wouldn't be a big deal (left as an exercise, if you will).

Comment: @Barry Then the formulation of your question was wrong. Even in your edited question, it is unclear to me what you want to achieve. You only say "list them like" and then given three example rows. Do you want to sort them by date, by filename, by very-special-foo-random-sort?!

Comment: Sorry to have confused you.I want to sort them by date