# How to order files in R according to certain "date parts" of their names

Tags: r

My question is similar to this question:[How to change the order of display of list.files(): for example based on part of the whole name of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161797/how-to-change-the-order-of-display-of-list-files-for-example-based-on-part-of)

but my case is differnt. I used the solution provided:

```
              a=a[order(gsub('.*_(\\d{8})[.].*','\\1',a))]
```

but did not work for my case because the naming  in my case is different from that provided in that question.

I have several files in a directory. The naming of the files is complex,for instance :

```
 file.img
 file.img
```

I want to list the files so that I can work with them, it seemed that R listed them in a certain order.
R ordered the files alphabetically even if the data is not ordered correctly.for example these two names of files:

How can I tell R to change the default display of list.files , and **order**   the files based on _yearmonthday only  which represents yearmonthday in all files:

to list files in R we use this :

I used:

```
      mixsort
```

but did not ordered them as I want

Comment: it is not clear you files names are like `SM_OPER__20100801_20120330T235959_245_001_7_ssture.img` **or** `SM_OP_20120330T000000_20120330T235959_245_001_7_ssture.img`?

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading.  You are ordering files by certain parts of their names, while "ordering by date" suggests  `system("ls -t")` (with some switches to return the info to the `R` console).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just need to change the  pattern of the `gsub` function. For example:

```
xx <- 'SM_OP_20120330T000000_20120330T235959_245_001_7_ssture.img'
gsub('.*_(\\d{8}).*','\\1',xx)
"20120330"
```

So , the whole solution is :

```
 a <- list.files("D:\\semon", "*.img", full.names = TRUE)
 a  <- a[order(as.numeric(gsub('.*_(\\d{8}).*','\\1',a)))]
```

**EDIT** add an example:

```
   a <- list('SM_OP_20120330T000000_20120330T235959_245_001_7_ssture.img', ##2012-mars-30
          'SM_RE_20101130T000000_20110427T235959_245_001_7_ssture.img', ##2010-nov-30
          'SM_RE_20100901T000000_20090127T235959_245_001_7_ssture.img', ##2010-sep-01
          'SM_RE_20100904T000000_20090427T235959_245_001_7_ssture.img') ##2010-sep-04


a[order( as.numeric(gsub('.*_(\\d{8}).*','\\1',a)))]

[[1]]
[1] "SM_RE_20100901T000000_20090127T235959_245_001_7_ssture.img"

[[2]]
[1] "SM_RE_20100904T000000_20090427T235959_245_001_7_ssture.img"

[[3]]
[1] "SM_RE_20101130T000000_20110427T235959_245_001_7_ssture.img"

[[4]]
[1] "SM_OP_20120330T000000_20120330T235959_245_001_7_ssture.img"
```

Comment: @sacvf you are right. You should coerce **gsub** result to a **numeric**. See my edit please. I add an example to show it works.