# Why does order(order(x)) is equal to rank(x) in R?

Tags: r, sorting, rank

In this [post](http://www.portfolioprobe.com/2012/07/26/r-inferno-ism-order-is-not-rank/) it is stated that `order(order(x))` is the same as `rank(X)`.

While some experiments corroborate this...

```
#why is order(order(x)) == rank(x)?
x <- c(0.2, 0.5, 0.1)
x
## [1] 0.2 0.5 0.1
order(x)
## [1] 3 1 2
rank(x)
## [1] 2 3 1
order(order(x))
## [1] 2 3 1
```

I fail to see how this can be proved and, even better, intuited.

Related: [rank and order in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12289224)

Comment: With `ties.method = "first"` `rank` actually uses `sort.list(sort.list(x))`.

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka: This might be a question for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off look at what happens with an integer sequence formed from a permutation of 1:10:

```
>  set.seed(123); x <- sample(10)
> x
 [1]  3  8  4  7  6  1 10  9  2  5
> order(x)
 [1]  6  9  1  3 10  5  4  2  8  7
> order(order(x))
 [1]  3  8  4  7  6  1 10  9  2  5
> rank(x)
 [1]  3  8  4  7  6  1 10  9  2  5
```

The `order`-operation is its own inverse in this case. And since the `order`-operation always returns an sequence starting at 1, then any nested odd applications of `order` will be giving the same vector.

Order returns an index vector that can be used to sort the original vector. So the location of the smallest item is in the first position,  the location of the second smallest value is next, .... ,  and the last item is the location of the largest item.   So when you then again perform that operation on the index vector, the first item is now the index of the smallest index, and so on   .... and that the vector's rank.

Answer (score 0):

I think the intuition is something along those lines: rank is just a shortcut for "on which *position* would the item on the first, second, ... last *position* be if one sorted all items first".

Because we are talking about the *position of a position* of a vector we have to nest the `order` function.

As in the example above starting from the outer `order` function in the first position this one tells us where the smallest index is (= 2). Now the smallest index happens to be on the position where the number would be if you ordered it (this is what the `order` function does), so in the example above because the first number (= 0.2) is the second largest one it is on position number two.

So this is just a fancy way of saying that the first number would be on second place if you ordered the vector first - which is nothing else what the `rank` function gives.