# Sort a list then give the indexes of the elements in their original order

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have an array of n numbers, say `[1,4,6,2,3]`. The sorted array is `[1,2,3,4,6]`, and the indexes of these numbers in the old array are 0, 3, 4, 1, and 2. What is the best way, given an array of n numbers, to find this array of indexes?

My idea is to run order statistics for each element. However, since I have to rewrite this function many times (in contest), I'm wondering if there's a short way to do this.

Comment: Could you show an attempt you've made?

Comment: If you reverse the definition of the task, you get the same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071415/efficient-method-to-calculate-the-rank-vector-of-a-list-in-python

Comment: The example for this question is a bit ambiguous. There are two operations you could potentially wish to carry out. 1.) for each element in the original list, get that element's position in the sorted list. 2.) for each element in the sorted list, get that element's position in the original list. In your example, the sorted array indices `[0,3,4,1,2]` satisfy both  tasks, but in general this is not the case. For instance, given input list `[1,6,4,2,3]`, the output of task 1 is `[0,4,3,1,2]` and the output for task 2 is `[0,3,4,2,1]`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
>>> a = [1,4,6,2,3]
>>> [b[0] for b in sorted(enumerate(a),key=lambda i:i[1])]
[0, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Explanation:

`enumerate(a)` returns an enumeration over tuples consisting of the indexes and values in the original list: `[(0, 1), (1, 4), (2, 6), (3, 2), (4, 3)]`

Then `sorted` with a `key` of `lambda i:i[1]` sorts based on the original values (item 1 of each tuple).

Finally, the list comprehension `[b[0] for b in` ...`]` returns the original indexes (item 0 of each tuple).

Comment: This will create an enumerated list, sort it based on the original key, then return the associated index. A very efficient solution w/ regards to speed and code length.

Comment: Why thank you. I probably should've commented it, thanks for that, list comprehensions can be a bit hard to digest.

Answer (score 3):

Using numpy arrays instead of lists may be beneficial if you are doing a lot of statistics on the data.  If you choose to do so, this would work:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array( [1,4,6,2,3] )
b = np.argsort( a )
```

argsort() can operate on lists as well, but I believe that in this case it simply copies the data into an array first.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
>>> sorted(xrange(len(a)), key=lambda ix: a[ix])
[0, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

This approach sorts not the original list, but its indices (created with `xrange`), using the original list as the sort keys.

Comment: If you're generating the full list of indices anyway in order to sort it, why use `xrange` instead of `range`?

Comment: @MarkReed: I believe that `sorted` will consume the `xrange` one element at a time.  This means only one list will be generated (the sorted version); the list of unsorted indices will not be pre-generated and stored.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
from operator import itemgetter
indices = zip(*sorted(enumerate(my_list), key=itemgetter(1)))[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The long way instead of using list comprehension for beginner like me

```
a = [1,4,6,2,3]

b = enumerate(a)
c = sorted(b, key = lambda i:i[1])
d = []

for e in c:
    d.append(e[0])
    
print(d)
```