# How do I rank a list in vanilla Python?

Tags: python, ranking

Let's say I have an list:

```
[4, 5, 2, 1]
```

I need to rank these and have the output as:

```
[3, 4, 2, 1]
```

If two have the same ranking in the case:

```
[4, 4, 2, 3] then the rankings should be averaged -> [3.5, 3.5, 1, 2]
```

**EDIT**

Here rank stands for position of number in a sorted list. If there are multiple numbers with same value, then rank of each such number will be average of their positions.

Comment: And what if more than two have same ranking ?

Comment: What do you mean by ranking?

Comment: If more than two have the same ranking then you average the rankings of all of them.

Comment: Ranking as in which position, ie 1st, 2nd, 3rd...

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most efficient, but this works.

- `rank` takes a sorted list and an item, and figures out the rank of that item should be by finding where it would be inserted to go *before* all elements that are equal to it, and *after*, then averaging the two positions (using array bisection).
- `rank_list` uses `rank` to figure out the ranks of all elements. The `partial` call is just to simplify, and not have to sort the list again for each item lookup.

Like so:

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right
from functools import partial

def rank(item, lst):
    '''return rank of item in sorted list'''
    return (1 + bisect_left(lst, item) + bisect_right(lst, item)) / 2.0

def rank_list(lst):
    f = partial(rank, lst=sorted(lst))
    return [f(i) for i in lst]

rank_list([4, 4, 2, 1])
## [3.5, 3.5, 2.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: I timed the two solutions here with a list of 3 items: The solution I posted below took 59% longer to run

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this here:
[Efficient method to calculate the rank vector of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071415/efficient-method-to-calculate-the-rank-vector-of-a-list-in-python)

```
def rank_simple(vector):
    return sorted(range(len(vector)), key=vector.__getitem__)

def rankdata(a):
    n = len(a)
    ivec=rank_simple(a)
    svec=[a[rank] for rank in ivec]
    sumranks = 0
    dupcount = 0
    newarray = [0]*n
    for i in xrange(n):
        sumranks += i
        dupcount += 1
        if i==n-1 or svec[i] != svec[i+1]:
            averank = sumranks / float(dupcount) + 1
            for j in xrange(i-dupcount+1,i+1):
                newarray[ivec[j]] = averank
            sumranks = 0
            dupcount = 0
    return newarray
```

I would like to see if there are any simpler or more efficient ways of doing this.