# Find rank and percentage rank in list

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas, rank

I have some very large lists that I am working with (>1M rows), and I am trying to find a fast (the fastest?) way of, given a float, ranking that float compared to the list of floats, and finding it's percentage rank compared to the range of the list. Here is my attempt, but it's extremely slow:

```
X =[0.595068426145485,
0.613726840488019,
1.1532608695652,
1.92952380952385,
4.44137931034496,
3.46432160804035,
2.20331487122673,
2.54736842105265,
3.57702702702689,
1.93202764976956,
1.34720184204056,
0.824997304105564,
0.765782842381996,
0.615110856990126,
0.622708022872803,
1.03211045820975,
0.997225012974318,
0.496352327702226,
0.67103858866700,
0.452224068868272,
0.441842124852685,
0.447584524952608,
0.4645525042246]

val = 1.5
arr = np.array(X) #X is actually a pandas column, hence the conversion
arr = np.insert(arr,1,val, axis=None) #insert the val into arr, to then be ranked
st  = np.sort(arr)

RANK      = float([i for i,k in enumerate(st) if k == val][0])+1 #Find position
PCNT_RANK = (1-(1-round(RANK/len(st),6)))*100 #Find percentage of value compared to range


print RANK, PCNT_RANK
>>> 17.0 70.8333
```

For the percentage ranks I could probably build a distribution and sample from it, not quite sure yet, any suggestions welcome...it's going to be used heavily so any speed-up will be advantageous.

Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes the `bisect`module is surprisingly useful. A rank implementation in the answer of @tzaman in [How do I rank a list in vanilla Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294877/how-do-i-rank-a-list-in-vanilla-python) might be a good baseline, esp. if more often need to rank compared to the same large sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two slow parts of your code are:

- `st = np.sort(arr)`. Sorting the list takes on average O(n log n) time, where n is the size of the list.
- `RANK = float([i for i, k in enumerate(st) if k == val][0]) + 1`. Iterating through the list takes O(n) time.

**If you don't need to sort the list**, then as @ChrisMueller points out, you can just iterate through it once without sorting, which takes O(n) time and will be the fastest option.

**If you do need to sort the list** (or have access to it pre-sorted), then the fastest option for the second step is [`RANK = np.searchsorted(st, val) + 1`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html). Since the list is already sorted, finding the index will only take O(log n) time by binary search instead of having to iterate through the whole list. This will still be a lot faster than your original code.

Answer (score 6):

Sorting the array seems to be rather slow.  If you don't need the array to be sorted in the end, then numpy's boolean operations are quicker.

```
arr = np.array(X)
bool_array = arr < val # Returns boolean array
RANK = float(np.sum(bool_array))
PCT_RANK = RANK/len(X)
```

Or, better yet, use a list comprehension and avoid numpy all together.

```
RANK = float(sum([x<val for x in X]))
PCT_RANK = RANK/len(X)
```

Doing some timing, the numpy solution above gives 6.66 us on my system while the list comprehension method gives 3.74 us.