# Python rank list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, rank

I am trying to rank a list of dictionaries based on a common criteria. So my list looks something like this:

```
d = [{'key1': 0, 'key2': 1}, {'key1': 1, 'key2': 0}]
```

I want to obtain the rank (in reverse order) of each dictionary according to a criteria that I may specify. So, if the criteria is 'key1', the output should be:

```
1 0
```

If the criteria is 'key2', then the output should be:

```
0 1
```

I tried the following function:

```
def rank_simple(list, criteria):
    return sorted(range(len(list)), reverse = True, key = type(list).__getitem__(list)[criteria])
```

which gives the error:

```
TypeError: __getitem__() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

and

```
def rank_simple(list, criteria):
    return sorted(range(len(list)), reverse = True, key = list.__getitem__[criteria])
```

which gives the error:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

as per suggestions in [Efficient method to calculate the rank vector of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071415/efficient-method-to-calculate-the-rank-vector-of-a-list-in-python)

How should I solve this problem. Please note that I do not want to use scipy or numpy for this (if possible)

Comment: I don't understand where the values `1` and `2` come from

Comment: Use `key=lambda x: x[criteria]`.  Also, in `sorted()`, use `range(1, len(mylist) + 1)`.  How it is, you will be getting `[0, 1]` and `[1, 0]`, not `[1, 2]` and `[2, 1]`.  **Don't** use `list` as a variable name because it conflicts with the built-in type.

Comment: @gtlambert: He's using 1-based indexing.

Comment: @ScottHunter modified the question. Hopefully it is clearer now :)

Comment: @akhiljain: It was perfectly clear, just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def rank(data,key):
    # Make a list or ranks to be sorted
    ranks = [x+1 for x in xrange(len(data))]
    # Sort ranks based on the key of data each refers to
    return sorted(ranks, reverse=True, key=lambda x:data[x-1][key])
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that you try to pass a computed value to the `key` argument to `sorted`, whereas you need to pass a function that accepts one argument (each of the items to be sorted in turn) and computes the sort key from each item:

```
def rank_simple(list, criteria):
    return [index for index, value in sorted(enumerate(list), reverse = True, key = lambda item: item[1][criteria])]
```

Also, you got the usage of `__getitem__` wrong; either you access a dictionary item using `[]`, or you use the `__getitem__` call.

Comment: `def rank_simple(list, criteria):
    return sorted(range(len(list)), reverse = True, key = lambda x: x[criteria])
d = [{'key1': 0, 'key2': 1},{'key1': 1, 'key2': 0}]
print rank_simple(d, 'key1')`

Comment: This gives me the error `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: I'm sorry, got carried away by editing... I've updated to post now.