# Relative size in list python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of integers. Each number can appear several times, the list is unordered.

I want to get the list of relative sizes. Meaning, if for example the original list is `[2, 5, 7, 7, 3, 10]` then the desired output is `[0, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4]`

Because 2 is the zero'th smallest number in the original list, 3 is one'th, etc.

Any clear easy way to do this?

Comment: Almost duplicate of [Efficient method to calculate the rank vector of a list in Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071415/efficient-method-to-calculate-the-rank-vector-of-a-list-in-python) -- although it's slightly different when there are ties. The methods are mostly the same except `set()`.

Comment: In particular the method here is `dense` instead of `average`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a list comprehension with `dict`ionary and also use `set` for getting unique values, like below:

```
>>> lst = [2, 5, 7, 7, 3, 10]
>>> newl = dict(zip(range(len(set(lst))), sorted(set(lst))))
>>> [newl[i] for i in lst]
[0, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4]
>>>
```

Or use `index`:

```
>>> lst = [2, 5, 7, 7, 3, 10]
>>> newl = sorted(set(lst))
>>> [newl.index(i) for i in lst]
[0, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4]
>>>
```

Comment: The last value should be `4`...?

Comment: @Qiu Oh thanks for your catch, edited mine! :)

Comment: While this looks nice syntactically, you are converting the list to a set, then sorting it, for every single element in the index. This is *extremely* inefficient.

Comment: @MZ I am using `dict.fromkeys` now

Comment: @U11-Forward The issue is you call `sorted` len(lst) times

Comment: @MZ I am using `dict.fromkeys` now

Comment: @U11-Forward ?? Could you explain? why does `dict.fromkeys` make calling `sorted` n times better?

Comment: @MZ Ah so sorry, now I understand what you mean, my bad. my original code was doing the `sorted` function everytime.

Comment: @MZ I mean it does it for every element in the list

Comment: Thanks for the answer and discussion. For my purposes, complexity isn't a great concern, numbers won't be bigger than 50. Simple concise code is king.