# Question about Ranking of Documents using BM25

Tags: python, information-retrieval

I'm trying to rank task sentences of an occupation using bm25. I'm following  [this tutorial](https://github.com/dorianbrown/rank_bm25), but getting to this part I get confused "Ranking of documents
Now that we've created our document indexes, we can give it queries and see which documents are the most relevant" i want that the queries be every sentence that i have at my corpus column. How can i do that?

> !pip install rank_bm25
>
> import pandas as pd from rank_bm25 import BM25Okapi import string
>
> corpus = pd.read_excel(r'/content/Job-occ.xlsx')
>
> tokenized_corpus = [doc.split(" ") for doc in corpus['task']]
>
> tokenized_corpus = [] for doc in corpus['task']:
> print(doc)
> doc_tokens = doc.split()
> tokenized_corpus.append(doc_tokens)
>
> bm25 = BM25Okapi(tokenized_corpus)

here is [my data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vzzJLee07tnAQFbclYX6jzBPnldqdXlI/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104430837841044523647&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: For the record, this problem has nothing to do with BM25 or even NLP, it's just a simple programming question. You could get faster and better answers if you ask the question more accurately.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you just need to iterate over your list of documents, for example like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from rank_bm25 import BM25Okapi
import string


def argsort(seq, reverse):
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071415/efficient-method-to-calculate-the-rank-vector-of-a-list-in-python
    return sorted(range(len(seq)), key=seq.__getitem__, reverse =reverse)


corpus = pd.read_excel(r'Job-occ.xlsx')

tokenized_corpus = [doc.split(" ") for doc in corpus['task']]

bm25 = BM25Okapi(tokenized_corpus)

for doc_as_query in tokenized_corpus:
    scores = bm25.get_scores(doc_as_query)

    # show top 3 (optional):
    print('\nQuery:',' '.join(doc_as_query))
    top_similar = argsort(scores, True)
    for i in range(3): 
        print('   top', i+1,':', corpus['task'][top_similar[i]])
```

I added sorting and printing the top 3 similar documents, in case you want this (that's why I added the function `argsort`).